# Why does C#/CLR not support method override co/contra-variance?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, overriding, covariance

There are quite a few questions & answers about hacking around the limitation of C# not allowing method return (and argument) types to be changed to compatible types on overrides, but *why* does this limitation exist, either in the C# compiler or in the CLR? As I an see, there is nothing that could break if co/contra-variance was allowed, so what is the reasoning behind it?

A similar question could be asked for widening access parameters - eg overriding a protected internal method with a public method (something which Java supports, IIRC)

Answer (score 3):

Eric Lippert already answered this way better than I could.

Check out his series on [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx)

and

[How does C# 4.0 Generic Covariance & Contra-variance Implmeneted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-does-c-40-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implmeneted)

EDIT: Eric pointed out that he doesn't talk about return type convariance but I decided to keep the link in this answer because it is a cool series of articles and someone might find it useful if looking up this topic.

This feature has been [requested](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=90909) and almost 5 years ago Microsoft has responded with "Thanks for logging this. We hear this request a lot. We'll consider it for the next release."

And now I'll quote Jon Skeet because it would not be a proper answer on StackOverflow without an answer by Jon Skeet. [Covariance and void return types](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/12/13/covariance-and-void-return-types.aspx)

> I strongly suspect that the answer
>   lies in the implementation of the CLR
>   rather than in any deep semantic
>   reason - the CLR probably needs to
>   know whether or not there's going to
>   be a return value, in order to do
>   appropriate things with the stack.
>   Even so, it seems a bit of a pity, in
>   terms of elegance. I can't say I've
>   ever felt the need for this in real
>   life, and it would be reasonably easy
>   to fake (for up to four parameters) in
>   .NET 3.5 just by writing a converter
>   from `Func<X>` to `Action<X>`, `Func<X,Y>`
>   to `Action<X,Y>` etc. It niggles a bit
>   though :)

Comment: I know implmenedted is spelled wrong. But I just linked to it directly.

Comment: No, I have never answered this question. Those articles are about generic type variance. This question is about return type covariance. In my articles on generic variance, I explicitly call out that I am NOT talking about return type variance.

Comment: doh. My failing memory. I read them months ago and didn't reread them before posting this answer. :)

Comment: Again, I'm not referring to covariance between void and other object types, I'm referring to covariance on method overrides - overriding a method that returns an object with one that returns a string

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not talking about C#, but it helped me understand the issues better and maybe it will help others: [Why is there no parameter contra-variance for overriding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2995926/367464)

Answer (score 0):

Seams introducing covariance of return value has no essential drawback as Java and C++ have used. However, there's real confusion cased by introducing contra-variance of formal parameter. I think this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010614/1443505 in C++ is also valid for C#.

Answer (score -1):

It does, you just have to wait for VS2010/.Net 4.0.

Comment: This is only the case for interfaces though, not concrete types

Comment: But what was the reason for leaving it out in the first place? It seems a pretty useful thing to have, eg for the Factory pattern

Comment: @JaredPar - interfaces + delegates ;-p

Comment: "But what was the reason for leaving it out in the first place?"

See: http://blog.ryjones.org/2005/07/12/product-development/

Comment: This is incorrect. C# 4.0 does NOT add return type covariance. We've added generic type variance, which is completely different.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Joel's answer - the CLR has supported limited variance for a long time, but the C# compiler doesn't use them until 4.0 with the new "in" and "out" modifiers on generic interfaces and delegates. The reasons are complicated, and I would get into a mess trying to explain, but it isn't as simple as it seems.

Re making a "protected internal" method into a "public" method; you can do this with method hiding:

```
public new void Foo(...) { base.Foo(...); }
```

(as long as the arguments etc are all also public) - any use?

Comment: Yes, CLR 2 supported generic type variance. But it did not support return type covariance.

Comment: Method hiding would work, but it wouldn't act like a virtual method - a call on an instance of the supertype wouldn't be dispatched to the public override

Comment: Indeed; it has limitations... and because you can't override and "new" the same signature in the same type, you can't achieve proper virtual unless you introduce an *extra* type and an *extra* virtual call.

Comment: Bad answer. generics variance != override variance; method hiding != overriding