# Generics Problem - C# 3.0

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, casting

I have a problem:

```
class Base
{
}

class DerivedClass : Base
{
}

class Test<T> where T : Base
{
}
```

and something like so:

`Test<Base> a = new Test<DerivedClass>();`

I think there's a way around it in C# 4.0, but is there a way to do something like so in C# 3?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, there is no way.
Long answer: No, there is no way in neither C# 3.0 nor C# 4.0, because co- and contravariance is not supported in C# 3.0 at all and only on delegate types and interfaces in C# 4.0.

**UPDATE:**
If you want to save several instances of this class in a list, independent of the concrete type of `T`, one workaround could look like this:
Create an interface `ITest` that uses `Base` everywhere you would use `T`. Make `Test<T>` implement that interface and hide the methods from `ITest` by using explicit interface implementation. Use `ITest` as parameter type to your method.
Sample code:

```
class Base
{
    public int Info { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public int Info2 { get; set; }
}

interface ITest
{
    Base Data { get; set; }
}

class Test<T> : ITest
    where T : Base
{
    public T Data { get { return (T) (((ITest) this).Data); } set { ((ITest) this).Data = value; } }

    Base ITest.Data { get; set; }
}

List<ITest> list = new List<ITest>();
list.Add(new Test<Base>());
list.Add(new Test<Derived>());
```

If you just want to pass that class to a method without requiring a specific `T`, you can make your method generic as well:

```
void YourMethod<T>(Test<T> test) where T : Base
{
    Console.WriteLine(test.Data.Info);
}

YourMethod(new Test<Base>());
YourMethod(new Test<Derived>());
```

Comment: What do you mean on delegate types? Can you elaborate for C# 4.0 please?

Comment: Please read here about that topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: Also this answer explains why classes aren't co- or contravariant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-4-0/2734070#2734070

Comment: @Twinhelix: Please see update to my answer for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

That's covariance you want and there isn't much of a way round in C# 3.0, other than using casting.

A `Test<DerivedClass>` does not inherit from a `Test<Base>` even if `DerivedClass` inherits from `Base`.

Comment: You can't cast `Test<DerivedClass>` to `Test<Base>`!

Comment: Sorry, I meant casting from an `object`.

Comment: The code `Test<Base> a = new Test<DerivedClass>();` is not possible. No matter how you cast...

Comment: So if I had a method that takes in variable of type Test<Base>, I can not pass in something concrete like Test<DerivedClass> ? And there's no way around that?

Comment: Scrub my comment about casting from objects - I meant from Base. You would get round this by making your Test class non-generic and casting from Base to DerivedClass as and when you needed to. That's it, I'm afraid.