# Co/Contravariance? Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>> not satisfied with List<string>

Tags: ienumerable, covariance, contravariance

I cant wrap my head around why I cant call a method with this signature:

```
public void Test(Tuple<int, IEnumerable<string>> x);
```

like that:

```
Test(Tuple.Create(4, new List<string>()))
```

I think this has to do with co/contravariance but thats just a guess. Can somebody share his cleverness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `Tuple` class is not marked as co- or contravariant, the reason being only interfaces can be co- or contravariant. So the type parameters have to match exactly. [Here's the reason why classes can't be co- and contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-4-0/2734070#2734070).