# Why can't the OUT generic modifier by applied to classes as well as interfaces?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't there generic variance for classes in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Example:

```
interface foo<out T> where T : BaseThing { }
```

compiles

```
class foo<out T> where T : BaseThing { }
```

does not.

Is this just unsupported, or is there some reason why it can never work or doesn't make logical sense?

Edit: Here's what I Wanted to do in case someone was wondering...

```
        class BaseThing { }
        class DerivedThing : BaseThing { }

        class foo<out T> where T : BaseThing { }
        class bar : foo<DerivedThing> { }

        private void test()
        {
            foo<BaseThing> fooInstance = new bar();
        }
```

Comment: Well, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487) says that `out` is only supported for interfaces and delegates. As for why it  was designed that way, I am sure Eric Lippert will end up seeing this question and giving you a comprehensive answer (not enough use cases, or all use cases are not common etc...).

Answer (score 3):

The `out` modifier tells the compiler that the type parameter can be covariant.  This means that use of types of T could be more-derived.  Since you're using a specific class (e.g. a constructed generic type), there is only one instance of the concrete type so there is not a more-derived type in play.  Multiple types can implement an interface like foo, which means you're dealing with potentially different types of T, in which case one of those T types may be more-derived.