# Covariance/Conversion issue with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TestingTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strings = new List<string>();               
            INeedToPassThisMethodAListOfObjects(strings as List<object>);
        }

        static void INeedToPassThisMethodAListOfObjects(List<object> objects) { }
    }
}

1>------ Build started: Project: TestingTypes, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>c:\users\[censored]\TestingTypes\Program.cs(9,41,9,64): error CS0039: Cannot convert 
type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' via a reference conversion, boxing 
conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion
```

You might say that a List<string> *is a* List<object>, since a string is an object and C# 4 is supposed to support covariance in generic types.

- Why does the compiler say it can't convert the type?
- How do I pass "strings" to the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces can be variant; classes cannot. [See here for the explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Your code will work if you pass the `strings` collection uncasted and change the declaration to be

```
static void INeedToPassThisMethodAListOfObjects(IEnumerable<object> objects) { }
```

However, that depends on whether you need a `List` within this function.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, Tim the prize goes to you for being the first to note about class type variance versus interfaces.

Comment: Didn't I note this first? I don't care about points though so leave it like that :)

Comment: Ah Pluc you're absolutely right, you had Tim Rogers beat by 90 seconds now that I look.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: If @BarryFandango needs list functionality, in .NET 4.5 and later he can use `void Method(IReadOnlyList<object> objects)`. The interface `IReadOnlyList<out T>` is covariant in `T`, and `List<T>` and `T[]` and others implement `IReadOnlyList<out T>`.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because a `List<string>` is not a `List<object>`.

You can call `list.Add(new TextBox())` on `List<object>` but, obviously, the same call doesn't work on `List<string>`.

C# Generics only allow for Covariance if the generic type is immutable (which is my the cast from List to IEnumerable works).

If you need to pass the list to a method, you could try passing

```
listOfStrings.Cast<object>();
```

On the downside, if you use that solution, any modifications made to the list inside the method call will not be reflected in the original list (because the call to `Cast` creates a new list).

If you have control of the method `INeedToPassThisMethodAListOfObjects` and that method only needs to iterate over the collection rather than modify it, you can change the parameter type to be `IEnumerable<object>` in which case you'd simply be able to pass your `List<string>` without any issues.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: @BarryFandango - It's really not. Pay attention to the article. List<string> is an IEnumerable<object>. That is because IEnumerable objects are immutable (as I said in my answer).

Comment: I do not really know why you were downvoted. Well explained :)

Comment: The downvote was based on Justin's original answer, which was just the first line.  Not very helpful but got him to the top of the queue.  It's getting more fleshed out as I watch.

Comment: Or use `IReadOnlyList<out T>` (since .NET 4.5) as I commented in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the strings to objects. Theres a nice LINQ method to do so.

```
var strings = new List<string>();               
INeedToPassThisMethodAListOfObjects(strings.Cast<object>());
```

**Edit**

According to your own link,

> In C#, variance is supported in the following scenarios:
>
> - Covariance in arrays (since C# 1.0)
> - Covariance and contravariance in delegates, also known as “method group variance” (since C# 2.0)
> - **Variance for generic type parameters in interfaces and delegates (since C# 4.0)**

So IEnumerable would accept List

Comment: `strings.Cast<object>()` is semantically more correct since all strings are of type `object`.