# exception on accessing dictionary from list

Tags: c#, list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> dict = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

            Dictionary<string, object> master = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            master.Add("list", list);
            master.Add("dict", dict);

            List<object> mydict = (List<object>)master["dict"]; // this is where i get exception
            Console.Write("Count: ", mydict.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

It is throwing exception on  bold line. 
Why is this behaviour and how shall i access this element?
Thanks
Sumanth

Comment: You can only cast it to `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` cannot be casted to `List<object>` in most cases. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx to learn more about convariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 5):

Because there is no `List<object>` under dict key

```
var mydict = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)master["dict"];
```

Comment: Isn't `Dictionary<string, object>` an `object`?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: It is, but a `List` of those is not a `List<object>` due to type safety restrictions.

Comment: yep, but you can't convert type List<Dictionary<string, object>> to List<object> this is called covariance and contravariance and there are a lot of resources in the web about this. Erric Lippert have really good series of blog posts about this

Answer (score 3):

The value `master["dict"]` is a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`, while the code casts it to a `List<object>`. That does not work because `List<T>` [is invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0) on the type `T`. To use a simpler example, this is not valid:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var listOfObjects = (List<object>)list;
```

If you somehow know the type of item you are pulling out of `master` then you can cast it back to its proper type:

```
var masterDict = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)master["dict"];
```

Alternatively, you could cast the value to `IEnumerable<object>` because that interface is covariant on its type parameter:

```
// This is not really meaningful because you can cast to non-generic IEnumerable
// just as well, but it works as a demonstration of what is possible.
var mycollection = (IEnumerable<object>)master["dict"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` as a `List<object>` and probably thinking `Dictionary<string, object>` is an `object` right?

yes, that's right, **but** `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` does **not** inherit `List<object>` and therefor the conversion you are using is invalid!

as people before me said: do

```
(List<Dictionary<string, object>>)master["dict"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` methods you can cast to non generic interface like:

```
        ICollection mydict = (ICollection)master["dict"];
        Console.Write("Count: ", mydict.Count);
```