# Casting to a generic class with interface

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

**Updated with input from MarcinJuraszek**

I have a feeling I'm bumping into a co / contra variance problem here, but I'm not sure I understand how to fix it. I have a class like this:

```
public interface ISomeClass<TEnum, out S>
{
     TEnum Dim { get; }
     IEnumerable<S> Inc { get; }
}

public class SomeClass<TEnum, S> : ISomeClass<TEnum, S>
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    where S : IMyInterface
{
    public TEnum Dim { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<S> Inc { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a class that implements `IMyInterface`

```
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{

}
```

And, of course, I have a class with a `SomeClass` property:

```
public class MyContainer<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public SomeClass<TEnum, IMyInterface> MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now my problem is that I can't assign a `SomeClass<MyEnum, MyImplementation>` to the `MyProp` property because I get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime complaining that it can't cast the `SomeClass<MyEnum, MyImplementation>` to `SomeClass<MyEnum, IMyInterface>`.

How do I work around this?

Example, this doesn't compile:

```
var c = new MyContainer<MyEnum>();
c.MyProp = new SomeClass<MyEnum, MyImplementation>();
```

Here's a [dot net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6aZHxK)

Comment: Simple answer: use `public class SomeClass<TEnum, out S>`. This would be fine, if the members of `IMyInterface` type will not change after construction.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: To my understanding, you can't do that with a class, only an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure, but delegates can be contra-variance. Let me to verify this.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the hasty and wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it work by having your generic type parameter invariant (either covariant or contravariant, depending on its members). However, in C# you can only declare generic parameters invariant on interface, so you'd have to declare another interface:

```
public interface ISomeClass<TEnum, in S>
{

}

public class SomeClass<TEnum, S> : ISomeClass<TEnum, IMyInterface>
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    where S : IMyInterface
{

}

public class MyContainer<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public ISomeClass<TEnum, IMyInterface> MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

That would make following code compile:

```
var container = new MyContainer<DayOfWeek>();
container.MyProp = new SomeClass<DayOfWeek, MyImplementation>();
```

Another possible solution would be to use another interface, where `S` generic type parameter doesn't exist:

```
public interface ISomeClass<TEnum>
    where TEnum: struct, IConvertible
{

}

public class SomeClass<TEnum, S> : ISomeClass<TEnum>
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    where S : IMyInterface
{

}

public class MyContainer<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public ISomeClass<TEnum> MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

**Bonus** - as of why it doesn't work:

Let's imagine that your code compiles, and you can assign `MyClass<T>` to `MyClass<IT>` as long as `T` implements `IT`. You could have following class:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public List<T> MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

And do

```
MyClass<IMyInterface> instance = new MyClass<MyInterfaceImplementation>();
```

with that `instance.MyProp` would be `List<MyInterfaceImplementation>` but you had access to it as if it was `List<IMyInterface>` so you could try adding element of `MyOtherInterfaceImplementation` which would crash at runtime. Not fun.

Comment: Do you know why only interfaces and delegates can have variant type parameter?

Comment: I don't have answer to that question.

Comment: if anyone has interest in the whys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this runs me into the problem that I can't add any properties to the interface. If I add a property then the compiler complains that "the type parameter 'S' must be invariantly valid on..."

Comment: Change variance type using `out` instead of `in`. It will allow you to add get-only properties as well as methods that return `S`, but you won't be able to have set-properties and methods that take parameter of type `S`.

Comment: Thanks again, your input is really helping but I'm still not getting it working. I've updated the question to reflect my real situation a little more and include a fiddle. My `SomeClass` actually includes an `IEnumerable<S>` and maybe that's what's tripping me up here.