# Covariance in constructor

Tags: c#, json, serialization, covariance

Related to this earlier question: [Casting to a generic class with interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910861/casting-to-a-generic-class-with-interface) and taking some cues from here: [Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net)

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public MyClass<TEnum> where TEnum: struct, IConvertible
{
    public IBaseA<TEnum, abstractBaseClass> PropA { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IBaseB<TEnum, abstractBaseClass> PropB { get; set; }

    public MyClass(BaseA<TEnum, abstractBaseClass> propA, 
                   List<BaseB<TEnum, abstractBaseClass>> propB)  
    {
        PropA = propA;
        PropB = propB;
    }

    public MyClass() { }
}
```

Now *I think* I've got all my issues with `BaseA` and `BaseB` cleared up and I have JSON converters that can successfully produce those from JSON. The problem is this final parent class. I need to be able to either set `PropA` and `PropB`, or be able to pass in parameters to the constructor that are generics using classes derived from `abstractBaseClass`. For example:

```
 var foo = new MyClass<SomeEnum>(new BaseA<SomeEnum, DerivedClassA>(),
                                 new List<BaseB<SomeEnum, DerivedClassB>());
```

Doesn't compile.

Now I can do something like this:

```
var foo = new MyClass<SomeEnum>();
foo.PropB = new List<BaseB<SomeEnum, DerivedClassB>>();
```

But I can't figure out how to make this work in my JSON converter because while I can deserialize to a `List<BaseB<SomeEnum, DerivedClassB>>`, I can't assign it because at that point it's just an object and I can't cast it to the class I need. For example, if I try something like this:

```
foo.PropB = myJsonToken.ToObject<List<BaseB<SomeEnum, abstractBaseClass>>();
```

It'll compile, but fail at run time because the object deserializes as a `List<BaseB<SomeEnum, DerivedClassB>>` which isn't the same type.

I've tried various different takes on `.ToObject`, and `serializer.Populate` and just can't seem to find a way around this problem.

*Update*, this is what `IBaseA` and `IBaseB` look like:

```
public interface IBaseA<TEnum, out S>
    where TEnum: struct, IConvertible
    where S : abstractBaseClass
{
    TEnum Dim { get; }
    IEnumerable<ICVal<TEnum,S>> Include {get; }
}

public interface IBaseB<TEnum, out S>
    where TEnum: struct, IConvertible
    where S : abstractBaseClass
{
    TEnum Dim { get; }
    IEnumerable<S> Include { get; }
}
```

Comment: Is `IBaseA` covariant, contravaraint, or invariant with respect to its first generic argument?  What about its second generic argument?

Comment: `IBaseA` (and `IBaseB` for that matter) are invariant wrt to the first and covariant (marked with `out`) for the second generic parameter.

Comment: What about `ICVal`? It would far easier to understand the question if you would provide [a good code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That said, at first glance it seems that you are attempting to use contravariance where only covariance is allowed. I.e. you are assigned/passing-in the more-derived values, where you have only permitted the return of said values. Can you use `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead of `List<T>` in your assignment?