# Covariant and Contravariant Monadic Types ala Scala's List in C#

Tags: c#, list, scala, covariance, contravariance

I'm new to c# but relatively experienced with scala, I'm trying to make a mimic of scala's list class (which is extended by Cons and the static class Nil).  I was hoping to get the type behaviour it had as well, since .NET has supported covariance/contravariance since 4.0.  Allow me to show what I mean:

Scala REPL:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A

val x = new B() :: new B()
//this is type List[B]

val y = new C() :: new C()
//this is type List[C]

val z = new C() :: x
//This uses contravariance to figure out and infer that this is type List[A]!!!
```

In C# this will throw a compiler error because C and B are not the same type with ImmutableList.

There don't seem to be examples online and I'm still quite the novice with C# so I thought it would be wise to ask if C# could do this in any way before attempting blindingly (I am still trying but I'm also learning the rest of the language first as I go).

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like you want type inference when creating a list.  C# doesn't have that.

Comment: you're right, the thought had crossed my mind, but c# does have that with the "var" keyword, and I know there is also a way to manual parse through type annotations (which are kept at runtime in .NET, right?) and find the least common ancestor in the type heierarchy (this is rather ugly).

Comment: I just want the prepend/append operation to be able to do this type inference...is there a way?

Comment: `var` can only be used for assignments and will take the type of whatever is returned.  It was primarily added for use with anonymous classes where you will not know the type before run time.  But really there's nothing like the append and prepend operators in Scala that I'm aware of.

Comment: Well given that there is a way to find the ancestor (i've seen it in another stack overflow post) implementing this sort of pseudo type inference is possible and should be done so that new lists can still be created even if the type you're adding is of another sublcass of the same superclass...I'll look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In C# this will throw a compiler error because C and B are not the
>   same type with ImmutableList.

In C#, *classes are not co/contravariant*, these are properties of Interfaces and Delegates used via the `in` and `out` keywords. Remember, in C#, a `List<T>` is a *mutable list*, and doesn't work like the immutable `List[T]` in Scala.

What you can do is declare the base type for the `List<T>`:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<A>();
    list.Add(new B());
    list.Add(new C());
}

class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
```

Same goes for using an interface for `T`, but you can't go further than that. This will not compile:

```
void Main()
{
    var bs = new List<B>();
    var cs = new List<C>();
    var result = bs.Concat(cs);
}
```

For more on that, see [Why isn't there generic variance for classes in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0)