# Nested Generic Cast

Tags: c#, .net, generics

See the code below:

```
public class CustomList : List<string>
{ }

public class BaseService
{
    public BaseService(KeyValuePair<List<string>, string> p1)
    { }
}
public class DerivedService : BaseService
{
    public DerivedService(KeyValuePair<CustomList, string> p1) : base(p1)
    { }
}
```

I have a compilation error in `base(p1)`:
The compiler cannot cast `KeyValuePair<CustomList, string>` to `KeyValuePair<List<string>, string>`

(I used types `KeyValuePair` and `List` to simplify the example, but in my case, they are generic types that are not part of the framework).

I managed to refactor the code differently, but I'm still curious: it seems to me that it safe to do the cast in this case. Why does the compiler refuse it?
This is also surprising because if I replace `KeyValuePair` with an interface with the covariance out keyword (`IMyInterface<out T1, T2>`), it compiles.

Comment: Does your custom List inherit from IList or sth? How do you expect to be able to automatically converrt to List?

Comment: `KeyValuePair<CustomList, string>` and `KeyValuePair<List<string>, string>` are different types

Comment: There´s usually no need to even inherit from `List<T>`. Anyway what you want to achieve isn´t possible, because co-variance works only on interfaces (that´s why it compiles for you with`IMyInterface<out T1, T2>`).

Comment: For that to work `KeyValuePar` would have to be co-variant on the `TKey` but it is not because classes cannot be variant on generic types, you would need an interface type for that instead.

Comment: Imagine that **would work**: `public BaseService(KeyValuePair<List<string>, string> p1) { p1.Key = new AnotherListThatAlsoDerivesFromListString() }`. [Don´t put giraffes and lions together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase).

Comment: @HimBromBeere But `Key` is readonly.  The real issue is that variance isn't allowed on classes.

Comment: @juharr I know. But `KeyValuePair` is a `struct`, if we want to be pedantic.

Comment: My question is more about why the framework does not allow to do it, not really how I can do it. @HimBromBeere partially respond to my question. Also, I found very usefull information on this conversation : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0/2734070#2734070

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to replace KeyValuePair with interface with covariant generic argument:

```C#
    public class CustomList : List<string>
    { }

    public class BaseService
    {
        public BaseService(IKeyValuePair<List<string>, string> p1)
        { }
    }
    public class DerivedService : BaseService
    {
        public DerivedService(IKeyValuePair<CustomList, string> p1) : base(p1)
        { }
    }

    public interface IKeyValuePair<out TKey, out TValue>
    {
         TKey Key {get;}
         TValue Value {get;}
    }
```