# Class implementing Interface with subtype arguments

Tags: oop, java-8

Why I cannot do that? I get compilation error.

```
public interface A {

  void update(Object a);
}

public class B implements A{
     void update(Long a) {
     }

}
```

That is Java 8

I do not see here violating any OO principle.

That's really make my time difficult to implement a generic API...

(I try to get Generics out of the play because the generic API gets counter-intuitive)

Comment: Do you mean the other way around? `A.update(Long)` and `B.update(Object)`? Because right now this clearly is not type safe at all.

Comment: Right now this violates Liskov Substitution Principle. If you do mean `A.update(Long)` and `B.update(Object)`, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439649/why-are-contravariant-parameter-types-in-java-not-allowed-for-overriding).

Comment: I do not think it violates Substitution Principle because Long is SubType of Object. Where ever you have an Object you can substitute it with it's subtype.

Comment: Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of the program (wikipedia)

Comment: ...which implies preconditions must not be strengthened in a subtype (this is also on wikipedia if you scroll down), and "strengthening preconditions (about what can `a` do)" is exactly what you are doing here. I realised it's kind of hard to argue for LSP directly, since there are no objects of interfaces. I'm writing an answer right now that shows how broken the code is.

Comment: I do not think any precondition is violated. You see a new method that's why you say they are strengthened, I see the "same" method. By strengthening the article means new signatures. If there was a recursive resolving of  Substitution principle  by design there would be not violation.

Comment: `A a = new B(); a.update("foo");` Does it work? If not, `B` is not a valid substitute for `A`. As simple as that.

Comment: As @Eran's answer seems a one way solution, I think this is the closest I am searching for in order to avoid those hardcoded  if checks inside the implementations as it is a well known problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You get a compilation error because `void update(Long a)` does not implement `void update(Object a)`.

You can implement it as follows:

```
public class B implements A {
    void update(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Long)) {
            // possibly throw an exception
        }
        Long a = (Long) o;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class that implements an interface must implement all the methods declared in the interface. The methods must have the exact same signature (name + parameters) as declared in the interface. The class does not need to implement (declare) the variables of an interface. Only the methods.

### Source:

[http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html#:~:text=A%20class%20that%20implements%20an,Only%20the%20methods](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html#:%7E:text=A%20class%20that%20implements%20an,Only%20the%20methods).