# Why does java allow for overriding methods with subclass return types but not subclass parameters?

Tags: java, overriding

If I have an abstract (or any as far as I know) superclass in java like so:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public abstract Person getPerson(Person p);
}
```

I noticed that a subclass can use itself for the return type, but not the parameter when overriding this method:

```
public class Child extends Person {
    @Override
    public Child getPerson(Person p) { //Works fine
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPerson(Child p) { //Doesn't work
        return this;
    }
}
```

Why is this not allowed? I'm not asking for a solution - I know I could just use an `instanceof` check in the method or something, I'm more asking why the former is acceptable and the latter is not to the compiler.

Comment: You can be more specific in what you *return*, since being more specific is guaranteed to satisfy the caller. They want a Person, and a Child is a person. You cannot be more specific in what you *accept*. They want to provide a Person; you cannot change the contract and you will only accept a Child now.

Comment: when you pass a Child, it's not an override, it's an overload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parameters allow doing this, they are called [contravariant parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439649/why-are-contravariant-parameter-types-in-java-not-allowed-for-overriding). When you do it with return types, they are called [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). Java supports covariant return types but not contravariant parameters.

That would change the method signature and it will no longer be an override. Return types are not part of the method signature but the type and the number of parameters of the method are part of the signature, hence this would interfere with overloading.

Moreover, if Java allowed you to do that, that would cause unexpected behavior in some cases and break runtime polymorphism with virtual methods because you are narrowing down what the method could accept.

Imagine a scenario where some code or an API only exposes the base class to you. You call `someMethod()` to receive a person:

```
public Person someMethod()
{
    Child child = new Child();
    return child;
}
```

This is how it would look like at the calling site:

```
Person receivedPerson = someMethod();
Person myPerson = new Person();
Person result = receivedPerson.getPerson(myPerson); // This will fail
```

Here, the caller does not know that `someMethod()` has actually returned a `Child` instead of a `Person`. I would think the `Person` class has a method called `getPerson()` accepting an object of type `Person` and therefore, I can call `receivedPerson.getPerson(myPerson)`. But, as the derived type `Child` which you don't even know about has changed the parameter type of `getPerson()` to `Child`, it will not be able to accept `myPerson` because you cannot convert an object of the base class to an object of a derived class.

This will never happen with covariant return types because if a method returns a more specific type, say `Child` instead of `Person`, it can be easily stored in a `Person` variable and child will always have all the state and behavior as that of its parent.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the guarantees that the compiler is enforcing to ensure that client code referencing the superclass method is going to be compatible with the subclass.

Because you're allowed to do this:

```
Person person = new Child();
Person result = person.getPerson();
```

Nothing is broken when `result` actually contains a `Child` object. A `Child` *is a* `Person`.

Now, if you try to apply the same logic to a method parameter, i.e., if you were to assume that it should be okay to call `getPerson()` with a `Child` instance, you would run into a problem:

```
Child child = new Child();
```

If the compiler were to allow this (as a call to `Child.getPerson(Child)`):

```
Person childResult = child.getPerson(child);
```

The following would be broken:

```
Person childPerson = child;
Person childResult = childPerson.getPerson(childPerson); //broken
```

This is broken because you think you're calling the "override", whereas you are not. The compiler is making sure that the contract declared with `Person.getPerson()` is upheld by all classes that extend person. It's okay to add `Child.getPerson(Child)`, but this would not be overriding `Person.getPerson(Person)`, it would be overloading it. This is because `Person.getPerson(Person)` should be possible to invoke with **any** subclass of `Person`. What if you had a different subclass, `Infant`, that extended `Person` directly? How would it work if you called `child.getPerson(infant)`? The compiler enforces that *any* kind of `Person` should be possible to pass to `Person.getPerson(Person)` or any subclass method overriding it.

In contrast, that is not a problem with the return type. As long as the overriding method returns a `Person` object, the caller will be able to deal with it, because the caller is prepared to receive a `Person` object, not any particular subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Because the method signature in Java is the name of the method, type, number and order of the parameters. It doesn’t depend on the return type.

For your scenario, `getPerson(Person p)` method exists in the parent class and, therefore, by rules of inheritance it can be overridden. But the method `getPerson(Child p)` is not in the parent class. That's why it is not working and throwing an error. The return type of the methods is not playing any role here. Hope that explains your curiosity.