# Why cannot use instance of interface implementation as parameter and return type?

Tags: java, oop

I would like to ask you why usage `@Override` in this case produces an error "`Method does not override method from its superclass`"? Why I cannot use instance of the class implemented an interface as a parameter and return type of the metod defined by same interface?

```
 public interface Request {
    //....
  }

  public interface Response {
    //....
  }

  public class MyRequest implements Request {
    //....
  }

  public class MyResponse implements Response {
    //....
  }

  public interface Order {
    Response cancel(Request request);
  }

  public class MyOrder implements Order {

    @Override
    public MyResponse cancel(MyRequest request) {
      return null;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Returning `MyResponse` is okay, but accepting only `MyRequest` is not: If you referred to a variable as `Order o = new MyOrder();`, you would expect `o.cancel(r)` to handle _any_ `Request r`, not just `MyRequest`. However, the return value being only `MyResponse` is okay: it will always be a `Response`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are contravariant parameter types in Java not allowed for overriding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439649/why-are-contravariant-parameter-types-in-java-not-allowed-for-overriding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would not work -- but inheritance requires it must.

```
class MyOtherRequest implements Request { ... }

MyOrder myOrder = new MyOrder();
Order order = myOrder; // okay because myOrder is a subtype of Order
order.cancel(new MyOtherRequest()); // unimplemented!
```

As a result, a subtype's method must accept *all* the possible values the supertype's method would accept -- not just a subset.

Comment: I see. So when I need to concrete parameter of my `MyRequest` implementation in `MyOrder#cancel`, I need to accept `Request` and cast it later to `MyRequest` myself, am I right?

Comment: Ideally if there's something you need in that method, `Request` would be able to return it, rather than relying on a concrete type. What's the specific information you're trying to retrieve from `MyRequest` that couldn't be abstracted within `Request`?

Comment: It's because of many different implementation of remote API, every API requires different values so I wanted to solve it by concrete implementation of `Request` interface for every concrete external API. In other words - I would like to have every `Request` implementation as simple as possible for every implementation of `Order` interface.

Comment: You shouldn't do any casting.  Instead, use generics so you have a type safe way of enforcing which orders can handle which requests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the parameter to cancel.

```
public MyResponse cancel(MyRequest request) {
      return null;
}
```

You can't pass a `supertype` to a `subtype` (In this case `Request` object to `MyRequest` parameter) as the implementation of the `subType` may have other methods that the `superType` interface is unaware of.