# Why can't I pass List<Customer> as a parameter to a method that accepts List<object>?

Tags: c#, generics

The following code gives me this error:

> Cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'.

**How can I indicate to the compiler that Customer indeed inherits from object?** Or does it just not do inheritance with generic collection objects (sending a `List<string>` gets the same error).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TestControl3423
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Customer> customers = Customer.GetCustomers();
            FillSmartGrid(customers);

            //List<CorporateCustomer> corporateCustomers = CorporateCustomer.GetCorporateCustomers();
            //FillSmartGrid(corporateCustomers);
        }


        public void FillSmartGrid(List<object> items)
        {
            //do reflection on items and display dynamically
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Jones", ZipCode = "23434" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Adams", ZipCode = "12312" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Jake", LastName = "Johnson", ZipCode = "23111" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Angie", LastName = "Reckar", ZipCode = "54343" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Jean", LastName = "Anderson", ZipCode = "16623" });
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you taking in List<object> items?

Comment: to do reflection on them and process them dynamically

Comment: You can still perform reflection on a `Customer` object just as you can on an `object`.

Comment: I'll be sending collections of other objects other than Customer, I fixed the code up a bit to reflect this.

Comment: not answering your question but probably solving your problem :) public void FillSmartGrid(List<object> items) could be rewritten to:
public void FillSmartGrid<T>(List<T> items). The compiler will figure out what T is so you don't need to supply it and since your just doing reflection in the method body that should work for all your types

Comment: @RuneFS +1 for your comment, solved my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.NET does not have co-variance and contra-variance (yet).

That B derives from A doesn't imply that `List<B>` derives from `List<A>`. It doesn't. They are two totally different types.

.NET 4.0 will get limited co-variance and contra-variance.

Comment: I don't think the covariance in .NET 4 will help in this situation.

Comment: @Mark Byers: why? looks like it should help a lot

Comment: @Mark is correct.  The covariance support being added to C# is limited to interfaces and delegates.  List<T> is a concrete type and cannot take advantage here

Comment: There is no covariance for lists, as it is neither "in" nor "out"

Comment: See also: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html

Comment: And actually, the CLI *does* have this - *C#* doesn't, except for arrays.

Comment: I may have fired off my answer a bit too soon. Should I delete or edit my post?

Answer (score 8):

That's the problem of covariance, and it is not as easy as it looks at first sight. C# 4 will have some support for that.

To get the idea of the problems, imagine in your case that this cast would actually work. Now you'h have a `List<object>`, which for instance also has an `Add` method. However, the argument for the actual `Add` must be a `Customer`, so that this clearly violates the implementation; the implementation does not provide the `Add(object obj)` method.

Unfortunately, some issues could have been solved by using a smart(er) design of the interfaces with generic methods where covariance is OK, such as for GetEnumerator.

Answer (score 7):

C# (at present) does not support variance for generic types.

However, if you're using C# 3.0, you can do this:

```
FillSmartGrid( customers.Cast<object>() );
```

Comment: +1 for this. If you are pre-version-3 then you can write a method to convert the List<Customer> into a List<Object>.

Answer (score 6):

It's because a list of a class is not convertible to a list of the base class. It's a deliberate decision to make the language safe. This question gets asked often.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/how-to-convert-list-of-derived-class-objects-to-list-of-base-class-objects/1817332#1817332) is my standard answer of how to work around the issue:

```
List<A> listOfA = new List<C>().ConvertAll(x => (A)x);
```

or:

```
List<A> listOfA = new List<C>().Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778030/cast-concrete-class-to-generic-base-interface/1779274#1779274) is really good explanation from Eric Lippert himself, one of the chief architects on the C# team.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered ad-nauseum in many other answers. The short answer is this:

Consider I have these variables:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(); //ok, seems fair
List<object> objects = new List<object>(); // again, everything's fine
```

Now, here's where it stops compiling:

```
objects = customers; // sounds OK, since a Customer is an object, right?

objects.Add("foo");
```

Does that make sense now?

C# 4.0 will introduce limited ability to do what you're attempting, though being able to do *exactly* as you describe (assign a `List<Customer>` to a `List<object>` won't be allowed for the same reasoning I outlined above). See [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx) for more information, and a correction to some misinformation that's going around the interwebs.

To address your comment above, there's no reason that you can't perform the same reflection operations on a `Customer` instance as you can on an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing List which does not work for the reasons above, could you not simply pass just an object reference then get the list type afterwards, kinda like...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    class Customer {
        public int id;
        public string name;
    }

    class Monkey {

        public void AcceptsObject(object list) {

            if (list is List<Customer>) {
                List<Customer> customerlist = list as List<Customer>;
                foreach (Customer c in customerlist) {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            Monkey monkey = new Monkey();
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer> { new Customer() { id = 1, name = "Fred" } };
            monkey.AcceptsObject(customers);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't the parameter be of type IList?

public void FillSmartGrid(IList items)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Winston Smith's answer.

I just wanted to point out as an alternative (although this possibly isn't the best way to handle the situation) that while `List<Customer>` does not derive from `List<Object>`, Customer[] does derive from Object[].

Therefore, it is possible to do this:

```
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        // ...
        FillSmartGrid(customers.ToArray());
        // ...
    }

    public void FillSmartGrid(object[] items)
    {
    }
```

Of course, the downside is that you're creating an array object just so you can pass it to this function.