# Converting Generic Dictionnary<> to ICollection<> problem

Tags: .net, generics, c#-2.0

Here is an exemple of the situation:

```
public class ScheduleArea : IArea<Schedule>
{
//....
private Dictionary<int, ScheduleArea> subArea;
//.... 

#region IArea<Schedule> Members

public ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, IArea<Schedule>>> SubArea
{
     get {
        return (Collection<KeyValuePair<int, IArea<Schedule>>>)this.subArea;//Error here
     }

}

#endregion
```

subArea is containing a ScheduleArea that is in fact an IArea. Why does the conversion doesnt work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're assuming generic variance, which doesn't work at all until .NET 4.0.

The simplest way forward is going to be to do it manually (given the "c#2.0" tag I assume you can't use LINQ):

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, IArea<Schedule>>> list = new
    List<KeyValuePair<int, IArea<Schedule>>>(subArea.Count);
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ScheduleArea> pair in subArea)
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, IArea<Schedule>>(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
return list;
```

I would make this a method rather than a property though, given the amount of copying going on.

Comment: Jon: A small nitpick: `Dictionary<K,V>` does implement `ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.

Comment: http://bit.ly/6NMnTV here is the proof that Dictionary<K,V> does implement ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>>

Comment: but not `Collection<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the very popular problem of generic co/contra-variance. You're basically trying to cast a `Dictionary<int, ScheduleArea>` to a `Dictionary<int, IArea<Schedule>>`. Generics in .NET aren't assignable like that

However, you *could* cast it to an `IDictionary<int, ScheduleArea>` or `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, ScheduleArea>>`. To actually get an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, IArea<Schedule>>` you need to either change the `subArea` variable type or create a new dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, IArea<Schedule>> dict = new Dictionary<int, IArea<Schedule>>(subArea.Count);

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ScheduleArea> kvp in subArea) 
{
    dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

return dict;
```

Also, `Dictionary` doesn't inherit off `Collection` - you need to use `ICollection` instead

Comment: C# 2 - no var available. I'd also suggest that if there's no need for hashing any more, I'd just go with List instead of a Dictionary for the new collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the daily question about covariance.

See: [Why can't I pass List<Customer> as a parameter to a method that accepts List<object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834229/why-cant-i-pass-listcustomer-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-that-accepts-listobje)

and

[Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/how-to-convert-list-of-derived-class-objects-to-list-of-base-class-objects)

To sum up: each item will have to be converted into a new KeyValuePair for the new collection.