# Inheriting abstract classes with abstract properties

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract-class, type-inference, abstract-data-type

I have base class with abstract properties. I want all inheriting classes to override abstract properties. Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string WorkPhone{get;set;}
}

public abstract class MyBase
{
    public abstract Person Someone {get;set;}
}

public class TestClass : MyBase
{
    public override Employee Someone{get;set;} //this is not working
}
```

Base class has Someone property with `Person` type. I am overriding `Someone` property on my `TestClass`. Now I want to use `Employee` type instead of `Person`. My `Employee` class inherits from `Person`. I couldn't make it work. What should I do to avoid this problem?

Help appreciated!

Comment: You never implement `Person Someone`, and `Employee Someone` is not in the base class (`MyBase`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# covariant return types utilizing generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348760/c-sharp-covariant-return-types-utilizing-generics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you may be able to assign an Employee to a Person instance, but you can't also assign a Person to Employee instance. Therefore, your setter would break. You either need to get rid of the setter, or use a private backing instance and some casting (which I wouldn't recommend) which would look like:

```
public class TestClass : MyBase
{
    private Employee _employee;

    public Person Someone
    {
        get
        {
            return _employee;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!(value is Employee)) throw new ArgumentException();
            _employee = value as Employee;
        }
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing this approach also, but i don't like it. Given that i can't drop the setter, what do you recommend then? Or are OP and myself using this pattern wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Generics` if you want derived classes to use ethier `Employee` or `Person`

Something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyBase<T> where T : Person
{
    public abstract T Someone { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass : MyBase<Employee>
{
    public override Employee Someone { get; set; } 
}

public class TestClass2 : MyBase<Person>
{
    public override Person Someone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of return type covariance, which is not allowed in C# unfortunately.

See Eric Lippert's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237056/1195036).

Answer (score 0):

In short: Each `Employee` object is a `Person` object. But not every `Person` object is an `Employee` object.

That's why compiler complains because you want it to treat an `Employee` object as a `Person` object in some place **that a `Person` is explicitly required** - which can be any object derived from Person ***including*** `Employee`; ***not specifically*** `Employee`.

Note: @sa_ddam213 provided a solution in her/his answer if you really need to do this explicitly.