# How to Override abstract Property?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

```
public abstract class SampleA
{
    public abstract string PropertyA {get;set;}
}
```

How to Override abstract PropertyA ?

[image]

Comment: have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905432/what-is-the-use-of-abstract-override-in-c

Comment: Can you explain what are you exactly confused about? Can't you just subclass it and declare a property with the same name with the `override` modifier?

Comment: @Sweeper I tried overriding like below ```public class Sample : SampleA
    {
        public override string PropertyA = "Override";
    }```  but I am getting issue saying I can't override and I need to use new key word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheriting abstract classes with abstract properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597653/inheriting-abstract-classes-with-abstract-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you override your property you should write both `get` and `set`. In your case you create **a new** property with the same name but with another signature.

Comment: Thanks @Nolmagination that's clear :-)                                                                  
 ```  public override string PropertyA { get; set; } = "OK"; ```

Comment: Small nit pick. He has not event created a new Property but a field (because without `get` or `set` it's only a field.

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to override a property with a field**

Properties provide access to a field by `get` and `set` value accessors. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property) to better understand the difference. So because they are not the same, your IDE proposed you to hide the parent Property by using the `new`-Keyword.

> If you want to know why the `new` Keyword didn't work in your case, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c).

#### Improve your Design

In your Question, it seems like `PropertyA` in your code needs to be set on inherited classes, but can't be changed from outside. So maybe do it like this:

```
public abstract class SampleA
{
    // no setter -> cant be changed after initialization
    public abstract string PropertyA { get; } 

    // protected setter -> can only be changed from inside SampleA or Sample
    public abstract string PropertyB { get; protected set; } 
}

public class Sample : SampleA
{
    public override string PropertyA { get; } = "override";
    public override string PropertyB { get; protected set; } = "override";
}
```

#### How it's done with your current design

Do it like this:

```
public class Sample : SampleA
{
    public override string PropertyA { get; set; } = "override";
}
```

or even implement it with more behavior:

```
public class Sample : SampleA
{
    private string _propertyA = "override";

    public override string PropertyA
    {
        get { return _propertyA; }
        set
        {
            // Maybe do some checks here
            _propertyA = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nagaraj Hey I improved my answer a little to better match your estimated requirements and issues. Please take some time to read through. :)