# Returning the derived class instead of an interface

Tags: c#

Is it possible to return the derived class in an interface definition in C#?
Some kind of return type covariance.

For example:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    this GetAnimal();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    Dog GetAnimal() { return new Dog(); }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't support return type covariance, at least as of C# 6. It is a [very commonly requested feature](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/357) on the Roslyn GitHub, and was long before Roslyn even existed.

Eric Lippert wrote in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235877/c-sharp-covariance-on-subclass-return-types):

> The feature is not implemented because no one here ever implemented it. A necessary but insufficient requirement is that the feature's benefits exceed its costs.
>
> The costs are considerable. The feature is not supported natively by the runtime, it works directly against our goal to make C# versionable because it introduces yet another form of the brittle base class problem.

So sit back, hold tight, and cross your fingers for C# 7/8/9. But don't get your hopes up too much - as said, it's a high-cost low-benefit feature that would likely require modifications to the CLR.

For now, take a look at [Christos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023710/4037348).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to return the derived class in an interface definition
>   in C#?

Yes it is, if you define a generic interface.

```
public interface IAnimal<T>
{
    T GetAnimal();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal<Dog>
{
    public Dog GetAnimal() { return new Dog(); }
}
```

You could read further on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not what OP expects.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev you are correct. I just corrected correspondingly my answer. Thanks

Comment: I had the same idea, but well, it is not as clean as I would like to have it. This is a really simplified example which gets quiet complicated in the real use case :/

Answer (score 1):

Sure if you pass the derived class as a type constraint :)

```
public interface IAnimal<T>
{
    T GetAnimal();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal<Dog>
{
    public Dog GetAnimal() { return new Dog(); }
}
```