# Heterogenic list of delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

Is it possible to create a list containing delegates of different types ?
For example considere this two delegates :

```
class MyEventArg1 : EventArgs {}
class MyEventArg2 : EventArgs {}

EventHandler<MyEventArgs1> handler1;
EventHandler<MyEventArgs2> handler2;
```

I would like to do something like that :

```
List<EventHandler<EventArgs>> handlers = new List<EventHandler<EventArgs>>();

handlers.Add((EventHandler<EventArgs>)handler1);
handlers.Add((EventHandler<EventArgs>)handler2);
```

But the cast from one delegate to another seems not possible.
My goal is to store the delegates in a list not to call them; but just to unregister them automaticly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do this in C# 4.0 thanks to the [generics variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0) but until then you need to find another way (maybe [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)).

Comment: I'm not sure if variance help here. `EventHandler<>` is invariantly defined in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this doesn't work, the delegates are completely unrelated types.  Normally, generic types would have only System.Object as the common base type.  But here, since they are delegates, you could store them in a `List<Delegate>`.  I doubt that's going to help you getting them unregistered though.  But I can't really envision what that code might look like.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for a generic delegate declaration to specify that certain type parameters should be covariant or contravariant, which would allow the types of assignments you're after.  Unfortunately, the internal implementation of multicast delegates makes it impossible to combine delegates of different types (a "simple" delegate holds information about its type, along with a method pointer and a reference to its target; a multicast delegate information about its type along with holds the method pointers and target references for each of its constituent delegates, but does not hold any reference to the original delegates that were combined, nor does it hold any information about their types).  An attempt to combine an `EventHandler<DerivedEventArgs>` with an `EventHandler<EventArgs>` will thus fail at run-time.

If `EventHandler<T>` were contravariant with respect to `T`, an attempt to pass an `EventHandler<EventArgs>` to a standard event `AddHandler` method which expects an `EventHandler<DerivedEventArgs>` would compile, and would even succeed if no other handlers were subscribed, since the `EventHandler<EventArgs>` would be `Delegate.Combine`d with `null`, thus being stored in the event's delegate field as an `EventHandler<EventArgs>`.  Unfortunately, a subsequent attempt to add an`EventHandler<DerivedEventArgs>` (which is actually the expected type) would fail since its type doesn't match the delegate it's being combined with.  Microsoft decided this behavior would violate the Principle of Least Astonishment (if passing the "wrong" delegate will cause any problem, it should do so when that delegate is passed, rather than when a later one is passed), and decided to minimize the likelihood of the scenario by making it so that an attempt to pass an `EventHandler<EventArgs>` to a handler that expects an `EventHandler<DerivedEventArgs>` will fail compilation, even though the act could succeed if it was the only subscription.