# KeyValuePair Covariance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance, keyvaluepair

Is there a better way to mimic Covariance in this example? Ideally I'd like to do:

```
private IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> foos;

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> Foos
{
    get
    {
        return foos;
    }
}
```

But `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is not covariant.

Instead I have to do:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> Foos
{
    get
    {
        return foos.Select(x => 
            new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(x.Key, x.Value));
    }
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a struct; and structs don't exhibit variance in .NET.

You can of course solve this by writing your own covariant `Pair` interface and some simple helpers to convert between sequences of `KeyValuePair` and your custom `Pair` interface. This will let you do:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>();

var view = dict.GetCovariantView(); // IEnumerable< IPair<string, ICollection<string> > >
  
// Notice that you can _widen_ both the key and the value types:
var dictView = view.CastPairs<object, IEnumerable<string>>(); // IEnumerable< IPair< object, IEnumerable<String> > >

// The `CastPairs` call is actually unnecessary provided you don't use `var` for the left-hand-side assignment.
// ...this is due to the implicit (and identity-preserving) variant interface conversion in C#, e.g.:
IEnumerable< IPair< Object, IEnumerable<String> > > dictView2 = view;

Console.WriteLine( Object.ReferenceEquals( view, dictView2 ) ); // --> True
```

Here's some example code that will let you achieve this:

```
// `out TKey` is for demonstration purposes. In production-quality code you probably should be using invariant key types.
public interface IPair<out TKey, out TValue>
    where TKey : notnull
{
    TKey   Key   { get; }
    TValue Value { get; }
}

public class Pair<TKey, TValue> : IPair<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : notnull
{
    public TKey   Key   { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }

    public Pair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.Key   = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public Pair(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair)
        : this(pair.Key, pair.Value)
    {}
}

public static class PairSequenceExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IPair<TKey, TValue>> GetCovariantView<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        if (source is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        return source.Select(kvp => new Pair<TKey, TValue>(kvp));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IPair<TKey, TValue>> CastPairs<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IPair<TKey, TValue>> source)
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        if (source is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hardly. KVP is a struct: Not an itnerface, is of ValueType.

Interesting [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208043/generic-variance-in-c-sharp-4-0) on variance.

I think casts are more performant, so I'd prefer to code like this:

```
private IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> foos;

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> Foos
{
    get
    {
        return foos;
    }
}
```

And cast `KeyValuePair.Value` to `ICollection` where I really need to. Frankly speaking it depends on how foos is used.