# Convert Object to Collection

Tags: c#, runtime, type-conversion

I have the situation where I am given an object and need to:

- Determine if that object is a single object or a collection (Array, List, etc)
- If it is a collection, step though the list.

What I have so far. Testing for IEnumerable does not work. And the conversion to IEnumerable only works for non-primitive types.

```
static bool IsIEnum<T>(T x)
{
    return null != typeof(T).GetInterface("IEnumerable`1");
}
static void print(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsIEnum(o));       // Always returns false
    var o2 = (IEnumerable<object>)o;     // Exception on arrays of primitives
    foreach(var i in o2) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
public void Test()
{
    //int [] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    string [] x = new string[]{"Now", "is", "the", "time..."};
    print(x);       
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you have generics why on earth are you using object? Why not print<T>(T obj)? Also, have you tried is IEnumerable instead of GetInterface? And for runtime checking you should not be using typeof, you should be using GetType.

Comment: Thanks, all. I used Snippet Compiler to test with and did not notice that it was "using System.Collections.Generic;" by default. I had tried non-generic IEnumerable and got errors until I changed to "using System.Collections".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is sufficient to check if the object is convertible to the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface:

```
var collection = o as IEnumerable;
if (collection != null)
{
    // It's enumerable...
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        // Static type of item is System.Object.
        // Runtime type of item can be anything.
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
else
{
    // It's not enumerable...
}
```

`IEnumerable<T>` itself implements `IEnumerable` and so this will work for generic and non-generic types alike. Using this interface instead of the generic interface avoids issues with generic interface variance: `IEnumerable<T>` is not necessarily convertible to `IEnumerable<object>`.

This question discusses generic interface variance in much more detail: [Generic Variance in C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208043/generic-variance-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the generic version of `IEnumerable`

```
static void print(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsIEnum(o));       // Always returns false
    var o2 = o as IEnumerable;     // Exception on arrays of primitives
    if(o2 != null) {
      foreach(var i in o2) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
    } 
}
```

You will miss some types that could be used in a `foreach` if you do it this way. An object that can be used as the collection in a `foreach` does not need to implement `IEnumerable` it simply needs to implement `GetEnumerator` which in turn needs to return a type that has a `Current`property and a `MoveNext` method

If the collection is typed and you simply need to support different kinds of collections you could do

```
static void print<T>(T o) {
    //Not a collection
}

static void print<T>(IEnumerable<T> o) {
   foreach(var i in o2) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
```

in this case the method overload resolution will pick the right method for you depending on whether or not the object is a collection (in this case defined by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Type t = typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable);

Console.WriteLine(t.IsAssignableFrom(T)); //returns true for collentions
```

Comment: Strings implement `IEnumerable` as well, so you need to filter strings out.