# Substituting implementations into the T of a parameterized class of type T

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Say I have a setup like

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface { }

public class MyClass<T> where T : IMyInterface { }
```

I figured out that I can't do a substitution like

```
var list = new List<MyClass<IMyInterface>>()
{
   new MyClass<MyImplementation>()
}
```

as I'll get the error

> Cannot convert from `MyClass<MyImplementation>` to
>   `MyClass<IMyInterface>`

Does that mean what I'm trying to do is code smell?

Comment: Its a compiler error so it means what you are trying to do is illegal in the c# language.

Comment: You cannot do that because `T` in `List<T>` is invariant. In other words, it has to be of one type (it cannot vary). Google covariance and contravariance. Also this question has been asked one too many times on SO.

Comment: I think what you want to look into is Variance with Generics in C#, the two key terms are Co-Variance and Contra-Variance. I'm not going to give an answer as it probably won't cover it well, as it's something that still gives me a headache, so my advice is to look up those terms until someone more knowledgeable can give you a good answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Variance in C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208043/generic-variance-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

It does not allow that because the `T` in `List<T>` is invariant. Here is an example which will explain:

```
public interface IFruit
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Apple : IFruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Orange : IFruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Let's add some fruits to a list:

```
var fruits = new List<IFruit>();
fruits.Add(new Apple());
fruits.Add(new Orange());
```

Later in the code, you have no idea what was added and you do this:

```
Orange orange = fruits[0];
```

Now that will not compile but it also does not make sense because every `IFruit` is not an `Apple` or an `Orange`.

**What if the compiler allowed it?**

If, for instance let's say, what you are trying was allowed by the compiler, like this:

```
// does not compile but let's say it did
List<Apple> fruits = new List<IFruit>();
```

Then if the compiler allowed that, it should also allow this since they both implement `IFruit`:

```
fruits.Add(new Apple());
fruits.Add(new Orange());
```

then later on somewhere in code you do this (since it is a list of apples):

```
foreach (var thisFruit in fruits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(thisFruit.Color)
}
```

**Crash!!** The compiler did not stop you at the beginning and at this point you are looking at the code and it says `List<Apple>`, and you wrote code and all compiled. At runtime, *oh crap*, there is no `Color` property because it is an `Orange`.

This is why it is not allowed.