# Generics strange conversion error

Tags: c#, .net, generics

My project structure is like this. I have an interface `IUnitOfWork` which has inside it

```
 void Commit();
 MyContext Context { get; }
 void Register(BaseRepository<IEntity> repository);
```

This is my UnitOfWork class

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, BaseRepository<IEntity>> repositories;

    public MyContext Context { get; }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        repositories = new Dictionary<string, BaseRepository<IEntity>>();
        this.Context = new MyContext();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        repositories.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Value.Submit());
    }

    void IUnitOfWork.Register(BaseRepository<IEntity> repository)
    {
        repositories.Add(repository.GetType().Name, repository);
    }
}
```

My IBaseRepository interface

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    List<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> filter = null);

    void Save(T item);

    void Create(T item);

    void Update(T item, Func<T, bool> findByIDPredecate);
}
```

My IEntity interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

 public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        unitOfWork.Register(this);
```

But I am getting this compiler error

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   '`Repositories.BaseRepository<TEntity>`' to
>   '`Repositories.BaseRepository<DataAccess.Interfaces.IEntity>`'

However I am explicitly specifying that the TEntity will be of type IEntity (or it will inherit of it). Why is this happening?

Comment: Regardless of the problem, why is a Repository registering itself in a Unit of Work?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064902/dependency-injection-in-unit-of-work-pattern-using-repositories?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa here.. Anyway with a few words, I will be using Dependecy injection and this way the repository will register itself when needed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto any idea why I am getting the compiler error?

Comment: Yeah, it's called variance. The linked question shows a non-generic `IRepository` interface that you did not copy.

Comment: I know why you are getting the error, but it is hard to explain. The reason is because `T` is invariant so it cannot be both `IEntity` and `TEntity`. I am sure if you removed the `GetAll` method, it will work (I do not have Visual Studio but that is my guess). Basically what you are trying makes no sense logically.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto now I thought, what if I want to concrete repository to have other methods different than the base repository?

Comment: That's when the entire pattern goes down, and one of the reasons I see absolutely no value in the UoW/Repository mess. You'd have to convert to the actual type every time

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, it already does UOW. Just make sure you use the same context in all your repositories.

Comment: So basically I should remove my UnitOfWork class and just inject the context with a Dependency injection container right?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50380618/4228458) will help with the error you are getting. As for UOW, imagine you have 2 repositories and add an item to each (customer, order). As long as both repos share the same DbContext, when you call `SaveChanges`, it will do the whole thing in one transaction. Either both customer and order will get saved or none of them. I am not sure what you are planning to do in your repo.Save method but you better not be committing changes to the db. I personally think you should rename that method Add.