# Upcasting with a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Is it possible to "upcast" from a generic class based on T, into a generic class based on something more general than T?

For instance, say I have a class named `Derived` that inherits from a class named `Base`. Can I ever do something like this:

```
List<Derived> der = new List<Derived>();
List<Base> bas = (List<Base>) der;
```

Or, using interfaces, is it ever possible to do something like this:

```
List<MyClonableType> specific = new List<MyClonableType>();
List<IClonable> general = (List<IClonable>)specific;
```

As written here, each of these examples fails with an `InvalidCastException`. The question we're arguing about is whether it's actually impossible, or simply a syntax error that could be fixed if we knew how.

Comment: Java has `<? extends X>` for this type of construct, I would be surprised C# doesn't have an equivalent.

Comment: C# has generic constraints (the where keyword) for the same thing as extends, but I'm not positive that's what Auraseer is after.  He wants to actually use variance on the collection from the looks of it.

Comment: @Romain, that cast is not valid in C#, but you can define a method like `void Process<T>(List<T> list) where T: Base {...}`

Comment: @finnw: I see... I guess the `where` constraint covers the typical use cases. The syntax is a bit heavy there, though (but more flexible than Java's)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C# 4.0 will have that feature.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-does-c-4-0-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implmeneted)

It will be enabled on interfaces and delegates which adhere to certain rules. `List<T>` won't be supported, as it is a concrete class. `IList<T>` also won't be supported, as its methods use `T` in both the `in` and `out` positions.

Comment: That link also tells me for sure that this cast is not allowed pre-4.0. That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Even in .NET 4.0 it will not apply to List<T>.

Comment: Good point. Variance is only supported on interfaces and delegates.

Comment: C# 4.0 will not have this feature for `List<T>`. It is inherently unsafe.

Comment: Nor will it have this feature on the interface `IList<T>`

Answer (score 1):

This

```
List<Derived> der = new List<Derived>(); 
List<Base> bas = (List<Base>)der;
```

is not possible and should never be possible. What happens here:

```
Base b = new Base();
bas.Add(b);
```

Kaboom! is what happens. If the above were legal `bas` would just refer to `der` and `der` can not add instances of `Base` which is what the `Add` would be trying to do. (For concreteness, think of `Base` as `Animal` and `Derived` as `Cat`; you can not cast a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>` because then you could add an instance of `Dog` to the casted list which would fail because it's really a `List<Cat>`.)

For similar reasons

```
List<MyClonableType> specific = new List<MyClonableType>();  
List<IClonable> general = (List<IClonable>)specific;
```

should never be possible.

In [C# 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183(VS.100).aspx) some of these issues will be solved with the notion of [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). For example, in C# 4.0 this will be legal:

```
List<Derived> der = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> bas = der;
```

This is because `IEnumerable<Base>` only spits out instances of `Base` and since all `Derived`s are `Base`s this is okay. Said another way, `IEnumerable<Base>` says "I know how to throw instances of `Base` at you" while `List<Derived>` says "I know how to throw instances of `Derived` at you." But as all `Derived`s are `Base`s, this means that `List<Derived>` also knows how to throw instances of `Base` at you. Therefore, it should be able to be assigned to an instance of `IEnumerable<Base>`. This is what is possible in C# 4.0. This is an example of covariance.

I must stress that for types like `List<T>` which have methods that both eat `T`s and spit out `T`s it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is nice LINQ extension:

> ```
> der.ToList<Base>();
> ```

Comment: I believe this method creates a whole new collection. It can be useful, assuming you've got Linq, but it is not the same as a cast.

Comment: It is true that you can specifically deal with IEnumberable<T> types this way, but it isn't an actual cast as the question asks. In this case, the ToList<Base>() method creates a new list of <Base> and fills it by casting each item from the original.

Comment: If you're only going to *read* the list (which is the only case where the cast would make sense) presumably it does not matter whether you are reading a copy or the original.

Comment: finnw, it does matter. If I copy an object and save a reference to the copy, then the original gets changed by some other piece of code, I'll never know about the change. Also, just doing the conversion can be very costly, whereas a cast is pretty close to free.