# How to specialize an inherited List<SuperClass> to a List<SubClass> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, collections

This sounds like a common problem, so whats the best practice if you have a base class A with a public property of type `List<SuperClass>` and you inherit that list in class B but want to use a more specialized type parameter for the list:

```
class SuperClass 
{
    public bool Flag;
}

class SubClass : SuperClass 
{
    public int Number;
}

class A
{
    public List<SuperClass> Elements { get; }
}

class B : A
{
   public List<SubClass> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

So how can in overwrite the Elements list with a new list, but still make sure it will be accessed if another class only knows A objects?

```
class C
{
    List<A> AList;

    void FillList()
    {
        AList.Add(new B());
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        foreach (var a in AList)
            forach(var super in a.Elements)
                super.Flag = true;  
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot override it because they are different types. Are you looking for [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) to hide the base implementation? `public new List<SubClass> Elements { get; set; }`

Comment: here's a good post you could read about this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231668/c-sharp-polymorphism-simple-question

Comment: Looks like a design problem. Why are you creating a List<A> when you want to put items in that list which are known by class B?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Because as it stands, if you insert a SuperClass through the A interface, B would fail, because SuperClass cannot be inserted into B's SubClass list.

The specific terms you should google are `Covariance` and `Contravariance`.

Your scenario can be solved if you restrict your classes to read access at least in the base class. Then you could have two read-only properties in your B class, one specialized, one not specialized but returning the specialized version.

Comment: yes, but whats the best practice in this case? can i construct a ReadOnlyList<SuperClass> from the List<SubClass> and publish this one?

Comment: @thalm best practice for what? Could you give an example of what your scenario is and how you want to use it? Sure you can use a ReadOnlyList, but that won't have any connection to the current list. Or you can use Covariance and Contravariance as nvoigt wrote and use `in` and `out` parameters. But "best practice" kind of depends on how you are going to use it

Comment: in this particular scenario the classes which only know A and the SuperClass need read access to the list and also need to sort the list by a float property of the SuperClass.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var c = new C();
        c.FillList();
        c.DoSomething();


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


class C {
    List<A> AList;

    public void FillList() {
        AList = new List<A>();

        var a = new A();
        a.Elements = new List<SuperClass>() { new SubClass(), new SuperClass() };
        AList.Add(a);

        var b = new B();
        b.Elements = new List<SubClass>() { new SubClass(), new SubClass() };
        AList.Add(b);
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        foreach (var a in AList)
            foreach (var super in a.Elements) { 
                super.Flag = true;
                Console.WriteLine(super.GetName());
            }
    }
}


class SuperClass {
    public bool Flag;
    public virtual string GetName() { return "super"; } 
}
class SubClass : SuperClass {
    public SubClass() { }
    public SubClass(SuperClass x) { }

    public int Number;
    public override string GetName() { return "sub"; } 
}

class A {

    public virtual IEnumerable<SuperClass> Elements {
        get{
            return elementList.AsEnumerable();
        }
        set {
            elementList = value.ToList();
        }
    }

    private List<SuperClass> elementList;
}

class B : A {

    public override IEnumerable<SuperClass> Elements {
        get {
            return elementList.AsEnumerable();
        }
        set {
            elementList = value.Aggregate(new List<SubClass>(), 
                                (acc, x) => {
                                    if (x is SubClass) 
                                        acc.Add((SubClass)x);
                                    else 
                                        acc.Add(new SubClass(x)); 
                                    return acc; });
        }
    }

    private List<SubClass> elementList;
}
```

I use IEnumerable. 
And convert `IEnumerable<SuperClass>` to `List<SubClass>` when setter property (of class B) was called.

Comment: this looks good and i also was as far as this, but IEnumerable is not enough in my scenario, i need random access with an indexer and also the ability to sort the original list.