# C# cast Foo<Bar> to Foo<object>

Tags: c#, generics, casting, covariance

does anyone know if it is possible to cast a generic type with a certain type parameter (e.g. Bar) to the same generic type with the type parameter being a base type of Bar (such as object in my case). And, if it is possible, how would it be done?

What I want to do is have a collection of `Foo<object>` but be able to add Foos with more specific type arguments.

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, this is called covariance. C# 4 has this feature for interfaces and delegates.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/

Comment: What he wants ("a collection of Foo but be able to add Foos with more specific type arguments") doesn't require C# 4 covariance - it works currently, and has since .NET 2.

Comment: @Reed: It looks like Michael wants to add `Foo<Bar>` to `Collection<Foo<Object>>`. This requires covariance from C# 4.

Comment: @Roman: Hrm... If that's the case, it'd require covariance.  Not clear, since there's no code shown.  That wasn't how I read it originally, though.

Comment: @Reed: there was a missing single quote in the text.

Comment: Pardon my english, but by adding Foos with a "more specific type argument" I mean objects of type Foo<T> whose type argument T is a subclass of the type argument supplied to the Collection. e.g:
`IList<Foo<Stream> list = new List<Foo<Stream>>()`
    list.Add(new Foo<FileStream>());
    list.Add(new Foo<MemoryStream>());

Please excuse me if I was being unclear.

Comment: Sorry if the above comment is unreadable - I can't edit it...

Answer (score 3):

You can have a collection of a base type with subclasses added.  For example, the following will work:

```
// Using:
public class Foo {} // Base class
public class Bar : Foo {} // Subclass

// Code:
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
HashSet<Foo> hash = new HashSet<Foo>();

list.Add(new Bar());
list.Add(new Foo());

hash.Add(new Bar());
```

Since "Bar" is a specific type of "Foo", it's perfectly legal to add it to a collection of Foo.

However, until .NET 4 and the [out modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487(VS.100).aspx) for covariance, you cannot do:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> list = new List<Bar>(); // This isn't supported in .NET 3.5...
```

Comment: Actually, you can't do that in .NET 4 either. `IList<T>` is neither co- nor contravariant, because T shows up as both parameters (in Add) and return values (in the indexer). With `IEnumerable<T>` it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ConvertAll method of List(T) or Array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx

Comment: He didn't really give any specifics.  The ConvertAll function or List(T) or Array are exceptionally handy at these points even if you have to convert from one collection to another.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible in C# 4.0!

You should look into [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487(VS.100).aspx).

Comment: This is not correct. You should say "Yes, it is possible from C# 4 onwards".

Comment: Technically it's not really available in C# 4 since you can only have covariance on Interfaces and Delegates not Types in general.

Answer (score 0):

Related:

[How is Generic Covariance & Contra-variance Implemented in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/)