# How to cast a generic class to a generic interface in C#

Tags: c#, casting, generics

according to below definitions

```
interface myin
{
    int id { get; set; }
}
class myclass:myin
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
[Database]
public sealed class SqlDataContext : DataContext, IDataContext
{
    public SqlDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString){}
    public ITable<IUrl> Urls
    {
        get { return base.GetTable<Url>(); }  //how to cast Table<Url> to ITable<IUrl>?
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update:**

```
public IEnumerable<IUrl> Urls
{
    get { return base.GetTable<Url>(); }
}
```

so by use above approach, i haven't Table class associated methods and abilities. this is good solution or not? and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# 3.0 and odler this is not easily possible - see also [covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0) in C# 4.0.

The problem is that `Table<Url>` implements the `ITable<Url>` interface - this part of the casting is easy. The tricky bit is casting `ITable<Url>` to `ITable<IUrl>`, because these two types aren't actually related in any way...

In C# before 4.0, there is no easy way to do this - you'll explicitly need to create a new implementation of `ITable<..>` for the right generic type (e.g. by delegation). In C# 4.0, this conversion can be done as long as `ITable` is a [covariant interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).

Comment: thank you, i also found another approach which is very easily (but i know this is not correct solution) so i'm now updated my question. can you check it out and tell me your suggestion's