# C# inheritance in generics question

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface A { 
 void aMethod(); 
}


public interface B : A {
 void bMethod();
}
```

Later I'm basically using a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, A> dict = new Dictionary<int, B>();
```

C# is saying I can't convert from the right to the left, even if I cast it.  Is there a way to use generics in C# so that this can work? If I make them abstract classes it seems to be ok but I need these as interfaces.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Dinah: Why would the framework version make any difference in this case?

Comment: @LukeH: because .NET 4.0 has Covariance and Contra-variance which may address this. If dmurph is having this issue despite being on 4.0, the issue would be different than if the issue occurred pre-4.0

Comment: @Dinah: C#4 introduced variance for generic interfaces and delegates, *not* classes, so would make no difference if trying to assign a `Dictionary<int, B>` to a `Dictionary<int, A>`.

Comment: It looks like I'm not even using 4.0.  Everyone here looks correct...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is what's referred to as generics variance (covariance and contravariance).  There is limited support for this starting in .net framework 4. Here's an interesting post: [How is Generic Covariance & Contra-variance Implemented in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0)

And here's the [MSDN entry on Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the msdn link, that was helpful, looks like I'll have to tackle my problem in some other way

Answer (score 9):

Nope it's a covariance issue.  If you could do:

```
Dictionary<int, A> dict = new Dictionary<int, B>();
```

It would be possible without a compiler error to put an object of Type A in dict.

The problem is that dict looks like: `Dictionary<int, A>` but it is really type `Dictionary<int, B>()` (so placing an object of Type A would throw a runtime error because of an invalid cast), so you shouldn't be allowed to even try to place an object of Type A in dict, which is why you can't do :

```
Dictionary<int, A> dict = new Dictionary<int, B>();
```

It's protecting you from making a runtime mistake.
You want to check out [Eric Lippert's blog on the subject](https://ericlippert.com/).

It's one of his favorite topics to talk about, so it's quite thorough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to find a way around your problem because the thinking behind it seems flawed. To illustrate, let's create another interface:

```
public interface C : A
{
    void cMethod();
}
```

Now, let's use your code:

```
Dictionary<int, A> dict = new Dictionary<int, B>();
```

What happens when I try the following?

```
C c = new ClassThatImplementsC(); 
dict.Add(1, c);
```

Take a look at [Eric Lippert's Covariance and Contravarience FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq) for many, many more details.