# C#'s equivalent of Java's <? extends Base> in generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, extends

In Java, I can do the following: (assume `Subclass` extends `Base`):

```
ArrayList<? extends Base> aList = new ArrayList<Subclass>();
```

What is the equivalent in C# .NET? There is no `? extends` keyword apparently and this does not work:

```
List<Base> aList = new List<Subclass>();
```

Comment: There isn't really an equivalent in .net, thank god

Comment: Your example shows broken type variance in java, .net doesn't have broken variance.. well, apart from one place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# inheritance in generics question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146764/c-inheritance-in-generics-question)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Actually there is an Equivalent(sort of), the `where` keyword. I don't know how "close" it is. I had a function I needed to do something similar for.

I found an [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4) about it.

I don't know if you can do this inline for a variable, but for a class you can do:
`public class MyArray<T> where T: someBaseClass`
or for a function
`public T getArrayList<T>(ArrayList<T> arr) where T: someBaseClass`

I didn't see it on the page but using the `where` keyword it might be possible for a variable.

Comment: Beautiful, almost exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

public class ImplementingClass<T> : BaseClass<T> where T : GenericBaseClass { ... }

Comment: This response actually qualifies as an answer

Comment: What an ugly way to have to accomplish this, but at least it does the job! +1

Comment: @Raystrom--can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806107/getting-behavior-of-javas-class-extends-map-in-net) which is related to your answer?

Comment: Here is another variation where  your class must implement IDisposable in addition to someBaseClass. public class MyArray<T> : IDisposable where T: someBaseClass

Comment: How do I use this to restrict T to numbers, such as `float` or `int`?

Comment: You have to use the Class version of the numeric type.

Answer (score 8):

Look into `Covariance` and `Contravariance` introduced with `.Net 4.0`. But it only works with `interfaces` right now.

### Example:

```
IEnumerable<Base> list = new List<SubClass>();
```

Comment: Just looking at this thread, trying to understand the C# way of generics. What happens, if the static type of your example is `List<Base>`, and if I want to add a `Base` implementor, which is not an instance of `SubClass`? Will that be a runtime error?

Comment: @decyclone--can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806107/getting-behavior-of-javas-class-extends-map-in-net) which is related to your answer?

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for two type generics, Take a look at this:

```
    void putAll<K1, V1>(Dictionary<K1,V1> map) where K1 : K where V1 : V;
```

Comment: @Guilheme--can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806107/getting-behavior-of-javas-class-extends-map-in-net) which is related to your answer?

Answer (score 7):

There is no *exact* equivalent (since the type system doesn't work in quite the same way, with type erasure and all), but you can get very similar functionality with `in` and `out` using [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233054.aspx).

Comment: @Mehrdad--can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806107/getting-behavior-of-javas-class-extends-map-in-net) which is related to your answer?

Comment: I have this problem since number of days, and this is second time I asked such question, can't get that why people can't answer it to the point

Comment: @Taufel: At first glance at least it looks like an "XY problem". What are you *actually* trying to do? Are you just trying to construct something? Because there's probably a way to do it that doesn't involve exactly matching the Java semantics (which may not even be possible).

Comment: Yeah I really want to do it with or without exactly matching the Java semantics but the end result (functionality) should be same at most

Comment: Is this really a difficult question to answer and by the way, less people used to approach this question? Hope you would do help in this regard :)

Comment: @Mehrdad--would you please like to ping me that are you going to help in this regard (so that I'll wait) or I have to go for some other?