# How do I assign an IList<T1> to an IList<T2> where T1 is a subtype of T2?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

### Preface:

I've read about Covariance and Contravariance in the question [C#'s equivalent of Java's <? extends Base> in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732494/), but switching my project to .net 4.0 doesn't seem to have worked.

---

Consider the following class constructor:

```
public Matrix(IList<RowVector> rows) {
    if (!Vector.AreDimensionsEqual(rows)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("foo");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows[0].Length; ++j) {
            Components[i][j] = rows[i].Components[j];
        }
    }
}
```

and the method `AreDimensionsEqual(IList<Vector> vectors)`:

```
public static bool AreDimensionsEqual(IList<Vector> vectors) {
    int dimensions = vectors[0].Dimension;

    for (int i = 1; i < vectors.Count; ++i) {
        if (vectors[i].Dimension != dimensions) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here, `rows` in the `Matrix` constructor is a list of `RowVector` objects, and I'm trying to use it as a parameter of a method call that requires a list of `Vector` objects. `RowVector` is a subtype of `Vector`.

I'm mostly familiar with Java, so if I were programming there, I'd define the method signature of `AreDimensionsEqual` to be `AreDimensionsEqual(IList<? extends Vector> vectors)`, but this syntax is not available in C#.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You can't. You'll have to convert it to a list of the other type.

Comment: How about using `IEnumerable<Vector>` as argument for the *AreDimensionsEqual* method (and then use either a foreach loop or a Linq expression in its body...)?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Variance in Java and C# are done in differently. Java has use-site variance while C# has declaration-site variance. The two are not equivalent. [Use-site variance is strictly more powerful than declaration-site variance,](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5479618/517852) so there will be patterns that you can use with variance in Java that will have no equivalent form in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic type parameter `T` in *IList<T>* is not covariant.

But the generic type parameter `T` in [*IEnumerable<out T>*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is covariant (note the [**out** keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd469487.aspx)).

Hence, you could alter your *AreDimensionsEqual* method to feature an *IEnumerable<Vector>* argument:

```
    public static bool AreDimensionsEqual(IEnumerable<Vector> vectors)
    {
        int dimensions = vectors.First().Dimension;
        return vectors.All(v => v.Dimension == dimensions);
    }
```

The code given is functionally equivalent to the *AreDimensionsEqual* method as shown in the question.

Comment: That's a very interesting solution. I've known about LINQ but have never taken the time to try and understand it yet. One thing that I'm noticing though (and I ran into this before while using IEnumerable<T> in another case) is that I'm getting warnings about "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable", possibly from Resharper.

Comment: @agent154, the LINQ expression in the code of my answer is functionally equivalent to the code in your question. But i think your intention is to check if any two vectors have the same dimension (or do you indeed want only check whether any vector has the same dimension as the **first** vector?)

Comment: Resharper warns you if you use Linq incorrectly in a way that would make your application slow. Sometimes the warning is given falsely, as Resharper cannot really understand the program context - but in any case one should double-check if this warning is substantiated or just a false alarm... :)

Comment: Your assumption was correct. I want to make sure that all of the vectors are of the same dimension. If one is not, then it fails.

Comment: @agent154 R# warns you about this because an `IEnumerable<T>` can be anything. Enumerating it may for instance execute a SQL query in order to produce results. ReSharper doesn't know what sits behind the enumerable and just assumes you shouldn't enumerate it multiple times by default. Call `myEnumerable = myEnumerable.ToList();` on it to enumerate it once and then reuse. Note that `ICollection<T>`/`IReadOnlyCollection<T>` can be enumerated multiple times safely.

Comment: I actually have an extension method for this case :) `public static ICollection<T> AsCollection<T>([InstantHandle] this IEnumerable<T> sequence) { return sequence as ICollection<T> ?? sequence.ToList(); }`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this because `IList` is invariant in its generic parameter.  As an example of why you can't do this, consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class C : A
{
}
```

Now imagine the following worked:

```
IList<A> listOfA = new List<B>();
listOfA.Add( new C() );
```

We just added an item of type `C` to a collection that is *really* of type `List<B>`.  We can't do that.  But as far as `listOfA.Add` knows, it's just a list of `A` and `C` is a perfectly reasonable thing to add to a list of `A`.

Comment: I don't see why this couldn't reasonably be possible... if C extends B, which extends A, then one would expect that if you make a list of A objects, that whatever methods you call on A should exist in both B and C.

Comment: @agent154 In his example the type of `listOfA` is actually `List<B>`