# Sorting custom class dictionary C#

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have a nested public class KeyCountMap

```
public KeyCountMap<T>  
{ 
   private IDictionary<T, MutableInt> map = new Dictionary<T, MutableInt>();
   public KeyCountMap()
   { }

   public KeyCountMap(Type dictionaryType)
   {
      if (!typeof(IDictionary<T, MutableInt>).IsAssignableFrom(dictionaryType))
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("Type must be a IDictionary<T, MutableInt>", "dictionaryType");
      }
      map = (IDictionary<T, MutableInt>)Activator.CreateInstance(_dictionaryType);
   }  

   public HashSet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>> EntrySet()
   {
      return map.ToSet();
   }  
   //... rest of the methods...
}
```

To sort out the values in map in descending order of values, if we use Java we can write method as:

```
public static <T> KeyCountMap<T> sortMapByDescendValue(KeyCountMap<T> map) 
{
   List<Entry<T, MutableInt>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<T, MutableInt>>() 
   {
      @Override
      public int compare(Entry<T, MutableInt> o1, Entry<T, MutableInt> o2)  
      {
         return (-1) * (o1.getValue().get()).compareTo(o2.getValue().get());
      }
   });

   KeyCountMap<T> result = new KeyCountMap<T>();
   for (Entry<T, MutableInt> entry : list) 
   {
      result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
   return result;
}
```

If we use C#, we can defined method as:

```
public static KeyCountMap<T> SortMapByDescendValue<T>(KeyCountMap<T> map)
{
   List<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>>(map.EntrySet());  
   // map.EntrySet() returns of type HashSet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>>  

   list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

   KeyCountMap<T> result = new KeyCountMap<T>();
   foreach (KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt> entry in list)
   {
      result.Put(entry.Key, entry.Value);

   }
   return result; 
}
```

Will this method work or is it necessary to override `CompareTo()` method (not used here) for sorting?

**EDIT**

```
public class MutableInt
{
   internal int _value = 1; // note that we start at 1 since we're counting

   public void Increment()
   {
      _value++;
   }

   public void Discrement()
   {
      _value--;
   }

   public int Get()
   {
      return _value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't guaranteed to return items in the order in which they were inserted, so what you're trying to do there probably won't work.

Comment: So how to sort out this problem i.e. sorting a dictionary ?

Comment: Please, have a look at `SortedDictionary<K,V>`

Comment: I have `IDictionary` not a `SortedDictionary` in class `KeyCountMap<T>`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If I use `SortedDictionary` instead of `IDictionary` in class `KeyCountMap<T>` then is there any need to write a method like that `SortMapByDescendValue()` ?

Comment: @Taufel: yes, you have to provide a *comparer*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a045f865(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DmitryBychenko moreover I have to sort by value instead of sort by key, as you suggested `SortedDictionary` it allows you to avoid sorting keys

Comment: @Taufel: yes, you have to compare pairs given by *keys*, but since you have both keys, you can obtain *values* compare them and return +1, -1, 0

Comment: I have to provide a *Comparer* but what about sorting by value?

Comment: How will you modify my C# version of method above using *Comparer*?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Do I need to override any method or all is this simply done inside that method ? Please demonstrate your suggestion via an answer

Comment: @Taufel, again, what is the purpose behind all this?  After seeing this question and [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37806107/800524), I see you're taking the line-by-line translation approach.  What are you trying to achieve?  Why don't you use a [`SortedDictionary<,>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx), or a list if insertion order matters?  Why `MutableInt`?  If you provide a context, you'll most probably obtain better answers.  As things are now, it seems you're trying to refurbish Java code to C# for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries (hashtables) don't have an order. Trying to order a hashset by controlling the order of insertion just won't work. If you want ordering, don't use a dictionary as your backing store.

Comment: Have a look at the `SortedSet` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Taufel Well, what do you need? You need a `Dictionary`, use one. You need a `List`, use one. I suggest you read up about the differences between the two. A dictionary is not a list.

Comment: If you see, the input parameter to the method `SortMapByDescendValue()` is of type `KeyCountMap<T>` whereas the sorting is being done using a `List`, so the issue is parameter of type `KeyCountMap<T>` which is a class using `Dictionary`

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar My question is something else, if you read my comment here and `.CompareTo` overriding in the question i.e. as if we use this just like `Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<T, MutableInt>>()` this in java

Answer (score 0):

If you want *permanently* sorted dictionary, you can try implementing sorting with `SortedDictionary<K,V>`:

```
  // Please, notice ...map => new... (C# 6.0 syntax) 
  // since you can't address map in the initializator (=)
  private IDictionary<T, MutableInt> map => new SortedDictionary<T, MutableInt>(
    // You are supposed to compare keys
    Comparer<T>.Create((leftKey, rightKey) => {
      // given keys, get values
      MutableInt left = map[leftKey]; 
      MutableInt right = map[rightKey];  

      //TODO: you may want to change logic here
      // you should return any positive integer if left > right
      // negative integer if left < right
      // zero in case left == right
      // current implementation (CompareTo) assumes that 
      // MutableInt implements IComparable<MutableInt> interface
      return -left.CompareTo(right);
    })
  );
```

**EDIT**: if you want to *represent* dictionary ordered by value, the best way is IMHO to make values *comparable*

```
public class MutableInt: IComparable<MutableInt> 
{
  ...
  public int CompareTo(MutableInt other) 
  {
    return (null == other)
      ? 1
      : _value.CompareTo(other._value);      
  } 
  ...
}
```

And then use *Linq*:

```
//Notice, that you can't return sorted values as dictionary
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>> SortMapByDescendValue<T>(
  KeyCountMap<T> map)
{
   return map
     .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value); // Value is comparable now
}
```

The only thing you can't do is to sort standard dictionary (`Dictionary<K, V>`)

Comment: For your notice here `MutableInt` is user-defined class updated above

Comment: @Taufel: I see; I've supposed that `MutableInt` is some kind of *integer* and that's why is *comparable* to each other, in other words `MutableInt` implements `IComparable<MutableInt>`

Comment: But its not getable for me that what you have given in your answer, is this a method in place of `SortMapByDescendValue()` or what else it is ?

Comment: @Taufel: OK now, could you, please, clarify, what are you looking for? A dictionary that *permanently sorted* (my current answer) or how to *represent* (print out etc) a standard dictionary content with values sorted in some order?

Comment: I am looking for: to give an object of type `KeyCountMap<T>` to the method that is doing sorting and return a `KeyCountMap<T>` type that is sorted by value descend, and what the object of `KeyCountMap<T>` will contain, you can see `KeyCountMap<T>` class given above

Comment: But where else have you used `.CompareTo()` method defined in this class `MutableInt`?

Comment: By the way I also have used `_list = _list.OrderByDescending(_x => _x.Value).ToList();` in my method definition