# Cast in List object

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface A, class B inherits from interface A.
I have a list of objects:

```
List<B> myB;
List<A> myA;
```

I want to assign myB to myA but I get a error "Cannot implicit convert type 'B' to 'A':

```
myA = myB;
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# inheritance in generics question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146764/c-inheritance-in-generics-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert each element of the list. It cannot be automatically converted for you. Easiest would be Linq:

```
myA = myB.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

**Update**: This question: [Why is this cast not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833447/why-is-this-cast-not-possible) discusses it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you: [Cast List<int> to List<string> in .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942/cast-listint-to-liststring)

Answer (score 0):

`IList<T>` is not covariant, where as `IEnumerable<T>` is, you can do the following..

```
void Main()
{

     IEnumerable<B> myB= new List<B>();
     IEnumerable<A> myA = myB;
}


public interface A
{
}

public class B :A
{
}
```

see this [previous SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034495/question-about-c-covariance)

Comment: Off topic : where did you get your avatar picture from ?

Comment: d:\icons\32x32\plain\dude1.gif - from our icons we use in our software, god know where they come from :)

Comment: d:\icons\32x32\plain\dude1.gif  ROFL

Comment: Best answer ever :D Have a chat together, my IP is 127.0.0.1 ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a way to convert between type `A` and type `B`.

There is no way to assign a list of one type to another, unless the type `B` is the same as type `A`.

You can use the `Cast<T>` operator for derived types:

```
class A {}
class AA : A {}

List<AA> aas = new List<AA> {new AA()};
List<A> bunchofA = aas.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

This only works when casting to less derived types (from descendant to ancestor). This won't work:

```
List<A> bunchofA = new List<A> {new A()};
List<AA> aas = bunchofA.Cast<AA>.ToList();
```

Because the compiler cannot know what to do to make the extra bits that `AA` has from `A`.

You can also, in a rather contrived way, use implicit conversion:

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
    public static implicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B();
    }

    public static implicit operator A(B a)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

List<B> bs = new List<B>{new B()};
List<A> bunchOfA = bs.Select(b => (A)b).ToList();
```

This will work in either direction, but might cause confusion, so it is better to create explicit conversion methods and use those.

Answer (score -1):

That is correct. List is a list of Apples and List is a list of .. err .. batmans! You cannot try to put one into the other.

Technically, you cannot refer to one as the other!

Comment: This is a contravarience/covarience problem, which has been fixed in C# in .Net 4.0

Comment: You are right. I didn't read the question correctly. My bad. I didn't see B was a derivative of A.