# Why can't I assign a List<Derived> to a List<Base>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance

I defined the following class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPackageCall
    {

     ...

    }
```

I also define a subclass of this class:

```
class PackageCall : AbstractPackageCall
    {

      ...
    }
```

There are also several other subclases of `AbstractPackageCall`

Now I want to make the following call:

```
 List<AbstractPackageCall> calls = package.getCalls();
```

But I always get this exception:

```
Error   13  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Prototype_Concept_2.model.PackageCall>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Prototype_Concept_2.model.AbstractPackageCall>'
```

What is the problem here? This is the method Package#getCalls

```
 internal List<PackageCall> getCalls()
        {
            return calls;
        }
```

Comment: It's called covariance/contravariance with Generics. Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0).

Comment: If you can return an `IEnumerable<AbstractPackageCall>` instead of `List<AbstractPackageCall>` then this will work as `IEnumerable<>` supports covariance.

Comment: You may also be interested in reading these two sites.  Reading this made co-/contra- variance click for me [C# 4.0 FEATURE FOCUS – PART 4 – CO- AND CONTRA-VARIANCE FOR GENERIC DELEGATE AND INTERFACE TYPES](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/13/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-4-generic-co-and-contra-variance-for-delegate-and-interface-types.aspx) and of course [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx) has a lot of posts on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, finally I think I understand the concept of covariance.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The simplest way to understand why this is not allowed is the following example:

```
abstract class Fruit
{
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
}

class Banana : Fruit
{
}

// This should intuitively compile right? Cause an Apple is Fruit.
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Apple>();

// But what if I do this? Adding a Banana to a list of Apples
fruits.Add(new Banana());
```

The last statement would ruin the type safety of .NET.

Arrays however, do allow this:

```
Fruit[] fruits = new Apple[10]; // This is perfectly fine
```

However, putting a `Banana` into `fruits` would still break type safety, so therefor .NET has to do a type check on every array insertion and throw an exception if it's not actually an `Apple`. This is potentially a (small) performance hit, but this can be circumvented by creating a `struct` wrapper around either type as this check does not happen for value types (because they can't inherit from anything). At first, I didn't understand why this decision was made, but you'll encounter quite often why this can be useful. Most common is `String.Format`, which takes `params object[]` and any array can be passed into this.

In .NET 4 though, there's type safe covariance/contravariance, which allows you to make some assignments like these, but only if they're provably safe. What's provably safe?

```
IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits = new List<Apple>();
```

The above works in .NET 4, because `IEnumerable<T>` became `IEnumerable<out T>`. The `out` means that `T` can only ever come *out* of `fruits` and that there's *no method at all* on `IEnumerable<out T>` that ever takes `T` as a parameter, so you can never incorrectly pass a `Banana` *into* `IEnumerable<Fruit>`.

Contravariance is much the same but I always forget the exact details on it. Unsurprisingly, for that there's now the `in` keyword on type parameters.

Comment: Why the downvote? If an answer isn't stupid, argumentative or offensive, always leave a comment so I could perhaps fix/correct things.

Comment: That's a great answer right there. Fair play to you for taking the time

Answer (score 3):

Now if you want to make the following call:

```
List<PackageCall> calls = package.getCalls();

// select only AbstractPackageCall items
List<AbstractPackageCall> calls = calls.Select();
calls.Add(new AnotherPackageCall());
```

I call this generalization.

Also, you can use this more specific:

```
List<PackageCall> calls = package.getCalls();

// select only AnotherPackageCall items
List<AnotherPackageCall> calls = calls.Select(); 
calls.Add(new AnotherPackageCall());
```

Implement this using extension method:

```
public static class AbstractPackageCallHelper
{
    public static List<U> Select(this List<T> source)
        where T : AbstractPackageCall
        where U : T
    {
        List<U> target = new List<U>();
        foreach(var element in source)
        {
            if (element is U)
            {
                 target.Add((U)element);
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your extension method requires two type parameters - and these will need to be included in calls to the method.

Answer (score 2):

### Why what you try does't work

You are asking the compiler to treat a `List<PackageCall>` as a `List<AbstractPackageCall>`, which it is not. It's another matter that each of those `PackageCall` instances is in fact an `AbstractPackageCall`.

### What would work instead

```
var calls = package.getCalls().Cast<AbstractPackageCall>().ToList();
```

### Why what you try will never be allowed to work

Even though each item inside the return value of `package.getCalls()` derives from `AbstractPackageCall`, we can't treat the whole list as `List<AbstractPackageCall>`. Here's what would happen if we could:

```
var calls = package.getCalls(); // calls is List<PackageCall>
List<AbstractPackageCalls> apcs = calls; // ILLEGAL, but assume we could do it

apcs.Add(SomeOtherConcretePackageCall()); // BOOM!
```

If we could do that, then we could add a `SomeOtherConcretePackageCall` to a `List<PackageCall>`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform this conversion, because a `List<AbstractPackageCall>` can contain anything that derives from `AbstractPackageCall`, while a `List<PackageCall>` cannot -- it can only contain things that derive from `PackageCall`.

Consider if this cast were allowed:

```
class AnotherPackageCall : AbstractPackageCall { }

// ...

List<AbstractPackageCall> calls = package.getCalls();
calls.Add(new AnotherPackageCall());
```

You just added an `AnotherPackageCall` into a `List<PackageCall>` -- but `AnotherPackageCall` does not derive from `PackageCall`!  That's why this conversion is not allowed.

Comment: That kind of conversion is allowed for arrays, which is probably why he asked this.

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<PackageCall>` does not inherit from `List<AbstractPackageCall>`.  You can use the `Cast<>()` extension method, like:

```
var calls = package.getCalls().Cast<AbstractPackageCall>();
```

Comment: Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Prototype_Concept_2.model.AbstractPackageCall>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Prototype_Concept_2.model.AbstractPackageCall>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?}

Comment: Yeah, just fixed my response.