# Why can this generic type not be converted?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following three classes/interfaces:

```
public interface IImportViewModel
{

}

public class TestImportViewModel : IImportViewModel
{

}

public class ValidationResult<TViewModel> where TViewModel : IImportViewModel
{

}
```

As TestImportViewModel implements IImportViewModel, why will the following not compile?

```
ValidationResult<IImportViewModel> r = new ValidationResult<TestImportViewModel>();
```

I understand what the error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ValidationResult' to 'ValidationResult'" means.  I just don't understand why this is the case.  Would this not be covariance?

Comment: I'm assuming your class _TestImportViewModel_ is supposed to be _TViewModel_?  (The code above does not show class TViewmModel at all).

Comment: Yes.  TestImportViewModel implements IImportViewModel and thus __should__ be able to be used as a TViewModel implementation as TViewModel : IImportViewModel.

Comment: @Sam TViewmModel(aka <T>) is a type of IImportViewModel its not a class .

Comment: @SamGoldberg, It's the generic parameter, often seen as `T` but in this case has a much more descriptive name.

Comment: [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653199/540345) a explanation of similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would this not be covariance?

Yes, except that in C# 4.0 covariance works on interfaces only. So you will have to make your `ValidationResult` implement a covariant interface (one for which the generic parameter is defined as `out`):

```
public interface IImportViewModel
{
}

public class TestImportViewModel : IImportViewModel
{
}

public interface IValidationResult<out TViewModel> where TViewModel : IImportViewModel
{
}

public class ValidationResult<TViewModel> : IValidationResult<TViewModel> where TViewModel : IImportViewModel 
{
}
```

and now you can do this:

```
IValidationResult<IImportViewModel> r = new ValidationResult<TestImportViewModel>();
```

Comment: You still cannot assign to `ValidationResult<IImportViewModel>` you can only assign to `IValidationResult<IImportViewModel>`. This is unfortunate.