# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type - Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class `Zone<T> where T: Media.Medium`. In this class I have a method `public void AddNode(Node node)` in which I have a statement `node.ParentZone = this` which raises this compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Zone< T >' to
>   'Zone< Media.Medium >'

But I can't understand why as `public abstract class Node` has `public Zone<Media.Medium> ParentZone` field and class `Zone<T> where T: Media.Medium` is constrained by `where T: Media.Medium`, so T is a `Media.Medium` under every circumstance.

Here is the isolated code: (Full of `Zone<T>` and a relevant part of `Node`)

```
public class Zone<T> where T: Media.Medium
{
    public readonly Type MediaType = typeof(T);
    public readonly Guid ID = new Guid();

    private readonly List<Node> _nodes = new List<Node>();

    public void AddNode(Node node)
    {
        foreach (var port in node.GetPorts())
        {
            port.Medium = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
```

> // Compile error in the line below

```
        node.ParentZone = this;
```

> // Cannot implicitly convert type 'Zone< T >' to
>   'Zone< Media.Medium >'

```
        _nodes.Add(node);
    }



    public List<Node> GetNodes() => new List<Node>(_nodes);

    public void RemoveNode(Node node) => _nodes.Remove(node);


}





public abstract class Node
{       
    public Zone<Media.Medium> ParentZone;

    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE #1:

My goal by this code is this: I want to add `Node` objects to `Zone` objects, `Zone` objects has a list of `Node` objects. Whenever I add a `Node` to a `Zone`, I want to set that `Zone` object as the parent of the `Node` object.

I am open to any refactoring to achieve this goal. It shouldn't have to be in this way if there is a better one.

Comment: Did u try to make the class node also generic?

public abstract class Node<T> where T : Media.Medium
{       
    public Zone<T> ParentZone;

}

Comment: No I didn't. I'm going to check this, thanks.

Comment: Well, changed `Node` to `Node<T> where T: Media.Medium` and used `Node<T>` instead of `Node` in class `Zone<T>`. But I got the same compile error after refactoring.

Comment: This is not about type constraints on generics; there are good reasons why you can't assign `Class<Derived>` to `Class<Base>` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653199/8166486) StackOverflow answer for some insight. That said, why is your Zone type generic? Looks like you are not actually using the T type parameter anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, gonna check that post. `Zone` is generic because I want to ensure (now or later) that every `Node` in a `Zone` has the same type of Medium which is T in `Zone<T>`. @FilipMilovanović

Comment: I see. Would making Node generic and changing the the add method work? `AddNode(Node<T> node)`, where T would determine the type of the parent in Node? Or is it that you don't know the exact type when you construct/connect the objects?

Comment: I did it (some other answers also suggested this) but it didn't change the error, still it says can't cast implicitly. And also, when I construct `Node` objects, I may or may not know in which `Medium` it operates. If I force it to `Node<T>` it can be a problem. @FilipMilovanović

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be clear that a generic constraint does not provide assignability between the generic types. Or expressed differently: A generic class is assignable to another class, if it inherits from the other class and shares *the same* type arguments. For example:

```
class Zone<T> where T : Medium { }

class ChildZone<T>: Zone<T>  where T : Medium { }

class Medium { }

class ChildMedium : Medium { }
```

What works:

```
Zone<Medium> mediumZone = new ChildZone<Medium>();
Zone<ChildMedium> childMediumZone = new ChildZone<ChildMedium>();
```

What does not work:

```
Zone<Medium> mediumZone = new Zone<ChildMedium>();
ChildZone<Medium> childMediumZone = new ChildZone<ChildMedium>();
```

Why? Because inheritance works within the generic class, not the generic arguments. Consider this:

```
class Zone<T> {
   T Value { get; set; }
}
```

An instance of `Zone<Medium>` can read *and* write items of type `Medium` in its `Value` property. That means it can read and write both, `Medium` and `ChildMedium`. In contrast, `Zone<ChildMedium>` can read and write only `ChildMedium`. The problem here is the setter, since it is impossible to assign `Medium` to `Zone<ChildMedium>.Value`, but not to to `Zone<Medium>.Value`. That makes the types incompatible.

If your `Zone` class would be an interface and you make sure that it only returns a value of type T, but you can not set a value of the type, you can use [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance):

```
interface IZone<out T> {
    T Value { get; }
}
```

If you need to read and write the value, your only choice is to make `Node` also generic and pass on the generic constraint:

```
namespace Core.Nodes
{
    public abstract class Node<T> where T : Media.Medium
    {       
        public Zone<T> ParentZone;

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Making `Node` class also generic didn't change the error. And the reason I think is: "Because inheritance works within the generic class, not the generic arguments". Right?

Comment: @Saibot Can you provide the code that does not work?

Comment: No, it works. I realized that I wrote mistakenly `public Zone<Media.Medium> ParentZone` instead of `public Zone<T> ParentZone`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you got an invalid declaration of your Node class

```
public abstract class Node<T> where T: Media.Medium
{       
    public Zone<T> ParentZone;
    ...
}
```

Comment: "invalid declaration of your Node class" - it is valid. It just doesn't do what OP expected it to do.

Comment: Well, changed Node to Node<T> where T: Media.Medium and used Node<T> instead of Node in class Zone<T>. But I got the same compile error after refactoring.

Comment: No, it works. I realized that I wrote mistakenly `public Zone<Media.Medium> ParentZone` instead of `public Zone<T> ParentZone`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a classic covariance/contravariance problem. If you don't want to make the Node generic (maybe it doesn't have to be generic at all?) then try to fiddle with this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index

If you declare specifically what you try to achieve, you may change your example and make it work. It requires adding an interface `IZone`.

```
public interface IZone<out T> where T : Media.Medium
{
    //important stuff here
}

public class Zone<T> : IZone<T> where T : Media.Medium
{
    ...
}

public abstract class Node
{
    public IZone<Media.Medium> ParentZone;

}
```

Comment: Gonna check this, thanks. And my intention (if it was not clear in question) is this: I want to add `Node` objects to `Zone`s, `Zone` objects has a list of `Node`s. Whenever I add a `Node` to a `Zone`, I want to set that `Zone` object as the parent of the `Node` object.

Answer (score 1):

You have said that type `T` inherits from `Media.Medium`, not `Zone<T>` inherits from `Media.Medium`. Here is a simple, hopefully illustrative example:

```
class Program
{
    class A<T> where T: B
    {
        public void Foo(B b)
        {
            T t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            //this is OK
            b = t;
            //this is not
            b = this;
        }
    }
    class B
    {            
    }
    class C : B
    {
        public void Foo(B b)
        {
            //this is ok
            b = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you say `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` instead of `this`. But I want the same `Zone<T>` object of given context. For example, when I add a `Node` to a `Zone` I want to set that particular `Zone` as a parent of added `Node`. Do you think `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` will do the job? Or will it create another object?