# Defining method taking an IEnumerable - type constraint or base class?

Tags: c#, generics

I asked a question earlier with regards to [using generic vs base class in a method taking in a `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502191/define-method-with-constrained-type-generic-vs-using-base-type). It was quickly pointed out that you can't pass a `List<Derived>` into a method expecting a `List<Base>`.

Further exploration (along with helpful links such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4652858/100534)) show that while you can't pass `List<Derived>` to `List<Base>`, you *can* pass `List<Derived>` to `IEnumerable<Base>` (due to contravariance/covariance in .NET 4).

So like in my previous question, I present the same one here: Since there doesn't appear to be a difference in using these two options, which would be better? Is it strictly a style-based thing, or are there implications to using one over the other?

Option A: `void DoWork<TBase>(IEnumerable<TBase> objs) where TBase : Base;`

Option B: `void DoWork(IEnumerable<Base> objs);`

Comment: Option A would enable to write something like `new TBase()` within the method ... just an advantage that comes to mind immediately.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You could add diffferent types to the first collection, too, using `Base` as `TBase`.

Comment: Indeed, unlike using `List<T>`, Using `IEnumerable<T>` will allow you to send to this method any instance that implements `IEnumerable<X>` where `X` is derived (or implements) `T`. So to the question of what is better - Well, In this case I don't think there is much of a difference between these two implementations. The Generic one might generate more compiled code, but I hardly think it's going to matter.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy No, it wouldn't - try it. You'll get an error: `Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'TBase' because it does not have the new() constraint`.  If you change the declaration to `where TBase : Base, new()` you could use `new` - but of course then you would only be able to use it with types that had a default constructor.

Comment: @MatthewWatson This is correct, simply forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Option A

```
void DoWork<TBase>(IEnumerable<TBase> objs) where TBase : Base;
```

Elements in the `IEnumerable` are constrained according to `TBase`. If `TBase` inherits from `Base` then the `IEnumerable` cannot contain `Base`.

Option B

```
void DoWork(IEnumerable<Base> objs);
```

The `IEnumerable` *can* contain `Base` or anything that inherits from it.

In either case, unless there's some ugly type-checking, each method can only interact with elements in the `IEnumerable` according to the definition of `Base` because that's all it "knows" about them.

The difference would be more meaningful if the method returned `Base` or `TBase`. Then the caller would be able to pass in `TBase` and get a result that is cast as `TBase`. If the type matters more to the caller than it does to this method then it wouldn't want to pass in an argument that inherits from `TBase` and get its result cast as `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

Option A jits slightly more, because `DoWork(new TDerived[0])` is a different method call than `DoWork(new TBase[0])`. There'll be a lot of shared code in the jitter's output (because `TBase` and `TDerived` must be reference types to actually be different and have one derived from the other), but it is a bit extra.

Theoretically if `DoWork` calls a virtual method and `TDerived` was sealed, then it's possible for the jitter to take advantage of that which would give a slight benefit, but I'm pretty sure that won't happen due to code-sharing. If it did happen the difference would be minute.

So, in all option B wins in not jitting more versions of the generic method and option A has no compensatory advantage.

However, option A could be more useful if it was:

```
TBase DoWorkAndReturnSomething(IEnumerable<TBase> objs) where TBase : Base
```

Where you avoid having to cast the result. This would only really be an advantage if you actually were casting the result. If you went on to use it as a `Base` or pass the result to a method that took a `Base` then you've won nothing to compensate for your extra jitting and extra conceptional complexity.

So there are pros and cons to each approach. The non-generic is likely to be the better for a wider range of cases, but there are times when the generic form with constraints does have an edge.