# Parent-Child Data Structure without an Explicit Leaf Node Class using Generics

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance, generics

I have the following example relationship:

```
namespace Yesod
{
    public class Program
    {
        //
        //
        //
        public struct Particle
        {
            public byte type;
        }

        //
        //
        //
        public class Entity<T>
        {
            public Entity<Entity<T>> Parent
            { get; private set; }

            //
            //
            //
            public Entity(Entity<Entity<T>> parent)
            {
                this.Parent = parent;
            }
        }

        //
        //
        //
        public sealed class Atom : Entity<Particle>
        {
            public Atom(Entity<Atom> parent)
                : base(parent) // Compile Error.
            { }
        }

        //
        //
        //
        public sealed class Molecule : Entity<Atom>
        {
            public Molecule()
                : base(null)
            { }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How would I solve the following compile error that the above produces?

```
  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Yesod.Program.Entity<Yesod.Program.Atom>' to 'Yesod.Program.Entity<Yesod.Program.Entity<Yesod.Program.Particle>>'
```

**Comment Reply #1:**
Specifically, the code is trying to assign an object of type

```
Entity<Atom>
```

to an object of type

```
Entity<Entity<Particle>>
```

as Atom is implemented as

```
public sealed class Atom : Entity<Particle>
```

whereby

```
Entity<Atom>
```

is expected to breakdown into

```
Entity<Entity<Particle>>
```

Comment: What you want to do? you structure is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the potential solution posted by Daniel Martin would never work (as admittedly warned), the explanation on why my code would too never work is 100% accurate, and it has led me to discover that C# 4.0 solves this otherwise expected functionality using its new [generic covariance & contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0) language features.

Below is the solution, for review:

```
namespace Yesod
{
    public class Program
    {
        //
        //
        //
        public struct Particle
        {
            public byte type;
        }

        // Fix with C# 4.0 using out keyword.
        //
        //
        public interface IEntity<out T>
        {
            IEntity<IEntity<T>> Parent
            { get; }
        }

        //
        //
        //
        public class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>
        {
            public IEntity<IEntity<T>> Parent
            { get; private set; }

            //
            //
            //
            public Entity(IEntity<IEntity<T>> parent)
            {
                this.Parent = parent;
            }
        }

        //
        //
        //
        public sealed class Atom : Entity<Particle>
        {
            public Atom(Entity<Atom> parent)
                : base(parent) // No more compile error.
            { }
        }

        //
        //
        //
        public sealed class Molecule : Entity<Atom>
        {
            public Molecule()
                : base(null)
            { }
        }

        //
        //
        //
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Now this can be done.
            Molecule water = new Molecule();
            Atom H1 = new Atom(water);
            Atom O1 = new Atom(water);
            Atom O2 = new Atom(water);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Daniel Martin. I could not 1-up you due to my current rep. score. To those wondering, the above is a silly mock up aimed to highlight obvious parent-child relationships to help those understand the question. The real-world intended use will be an advanced version that will be employed in the field of computer graphics to solve the Coherent Space Partitioning problem in a well-defined and recursive manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, but Java programmers occasionally slam into this issue too.

Looking around at other C# sources, I think you can do what you want (with a little loss in type safety) with:

```
    public class Entity<T>
    {
        public Entity<P> Parent
            where P : Entity<Entity<T>>
        { get; private set; }

        //
        //
        //
        public Entity(Entity<P> parent)
            where P : Entity<Entity<T>>
        {
            this.Parent = parent;
        }
    }
```

The Java answer would involve `? extends Entity<T>`. The basic issue is that although `Molecule` is an `Entity<Atom>`, there's no way for the compiler to know that `Molecule` is also an `Entity<Entity<Particle>>`.  After all, suppose that `Entity` maintained a list of children, and had the sensible `addChild(T child)` method on it.  Then the compiler would want to ensure that you only added `Atom`s as children of molecules. But if `Molecule` is an `Entity<Entity<Particle>>`, then nothing would prevent you from doing:

```
Entity<Entity<Particle>> downcast = myMolecule;
downcast.addChild(myNonAtomParticleBasedEntity);
```

The proper fully type-safe solution for this pattern involves *self types*, which Java and C# don't have. The Java pattern of `Foo<F extends Foo<F>>` ([and its C# equivalent](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/20/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-2-self-referential-generic-types.aspx)) comes close, but is very slippery to work with. Barring that, declare-time variance would make this pattern cleaner.