# Cannot cast between generic types

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to do this:

```
interface IA
{
}

class A : IA
{
}

class Foo<T> where T: IA
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Foo<A> fooA = new Foo<A>();
        Foo<IA> fooIA = fooA as Foo<IA>;
    }
}
```

However, the cast from `Foo<A>` to `Foo<IA>` does not compile. I recall seeing covariance issues like this when casting between `List<T>`'s, but I didn't think it applied to simple generics like this.

What is a good work around to getting this cast to work? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Some related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0/246101#246101

Comment: A `Foo<IA>` simply *isn't* a `Foo<A>`, and can't be made to be so. You haven't said what you're trying to achieve, which makes it very hard to help you towards a solution.

Comment: @Jon: The real example is substantially more complex, but this simple code I have provided is the bare bones of the problem. It all comes down to using generics to represent a base type, and those classes perform operations on those base types and NEVER need to downcast them, so the typical danger in this is moot since I will not be downcasting IA to an A (or a B, or C, or whatever it is).

Comment: @Robert: But without seeing the code within Foo, we can't tell anything about the safety involved, or the best way of working around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All generic *classes* are invariant. *Interfaces* (and delegates) on the other hand can support co- and contra-variance, but only in the cases where it's possible safely. And they need to opt-in explicitly.

For example via `IFoo<out T>` or `IFoo<in T>`

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IA
    {
    }

    class A : IA
    {
    }

    interface IFoo<T> where T : IA
    {
    }

    class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : IA
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IFoo<A> fooA = new Foo<A>();
            Foo<IA> fooIa = fooA as Foo<IA>;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> those classes perform operations on those base types and NEVER need to downcast them

Then why do you need a `Foo<A>` to begin with? Declare it as `Foo<IA>` and add `A`'s to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is in java but you could do something like this:

```
interface Alpha
{
}

class Beta implements Alpha
{
}  

class Foo<T>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo<Beta> fooBeta = new Foo<Beta>();
        Foo<? implements Alpha> fooAlpha = fooBeta;
    }
}
```

This doesn't solve the issue completely but you get you can at least get access to all of the Alpha methods without knowing about Beta...