# How to implement generic polymorphism in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting, covariance

to avoid confusion I summarised some code:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IManager<ISpecificEntity> specificManager = new SpecificEntityManager();
            IManager<IIdentifier> manager = (IManager<IIdentifier>) specificManager;
            manager.DoStuffWith(new SpecificEntity());
        }
    }

    internal interface IIdentifier
    {
    }

    internal interface ISpecificEntity : IIdentifier
    {
    }

    internal class SpecificEntity : ISpecificEntity
    {
    }

    internal interface IManager<TIdentifier> where TIdentifier : IIdentifier
    {
        void DoStuffWith(TIdentifier entity);
    }

    internal class SpecificEntityManager : IManager<ISpecificEntity>
    {
        public void DoStuffWith(ISpecificEntity specificEntity)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I get an InvalidCastException in `Main()`.

I know that `ISpecificEntity` implements `IIdentifier`.
But obviously a direct cast from an `IManager<ISpecificEntity>` into an `IManager<IIdentifier>` does not work.

I thought working with covariance could do the trick but changing `IManager<TIdentifier>` into `IManager<in TIdentifier>` does not help either.

So, is there a way do cast `specificManager` into an `IManager<IIdentifier>`?

Thanks and all the best.

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `IManager<IIdentifier>` you can do such thing:

```
IIdentifier entity = new NotSpecificEntity();
manager.DoStuffWith(entity);
```

That will lead to exception, in your `SpecificEntityManager`, because it accepts only parameters of type `ISpecificEntity`

UPDATE: 
You can read more about covariance and contravariance in C# at [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/)

Comment: ... and that's why it isn't allowed to do what the OP wants to do. +1

Comment: But `ISpecificEntity` implements `IIdentifier`. And `TIdentifier` in `IManager` accepts only `IIdentifier`. So, there should not be an exception in that line. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hmmm. You are right. I think I have to change my summarised code. It does not fit to the problem in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
ISpecificEntity bankAccountManager = new SpecificEntity();
IManager<IIdentifier> manager = (IManager<IIdentifier>)bankAccountManager;
manager.DoStuffWith(new SpecificEntity());
```

?

Comment: Because `SpecificEntity` is not an `IManager<IIdentifier>` but an `IIdentifier`.