# How to implement generic polymorphism in c# - Part 2?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting, covariance

I already posted [this question with a bad sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10211072/1341449).

This code should be better.

To avoid confusion I summarised some code:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IManager<ISpecificEntity> specificManager = new SpecificEntityManager();
            IManager<IAntoherSpecificEntity> anotherSpecificManager = new AnotherSpecificEntityManager();
            Dictionary<string, IManager<IIdentifier>> managers = new Dictionary<string, IManager<IIdentifier>>();
            managers.Add("SpecificManager", (IManager<IIdentifier>)specificManager);
            managers.Add("AnotherSpecificManager", (IManager<IIdentifier>)anotherSpecificManager);

            foreach (var manager in managers.Values)
            {
                IIdentifier entity = manager.Container.GetEntity();
            }
        }
    }

    internal interface IIdentifier
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    internal interface ISpecificEntity : IIdentifier
    {
        string SpecificValue { get; set; }
    }

    internal class SpecificEntity : ISpecificEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SpecificValue { get; set; }
    }


    internal interface IAntoherSpecificEntity : IIdentifier
    {
        string AnotherSpecificValue { get; set; }
    }

    internal class AntoherSpecificEntity : IAntoherSpecificEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AnotherSpecificValue { get; set; }
    }

    internal interface IContainer<out TIdentifier> where TIdentifier : IIdentifier
    {
        TIdentifier GetEntity();
    }

    internal interface ISpecificContainer : IContainer<ISpecificEntity>
    {
    }

    internal class SpecificContainer : ISpecificContainer
    {
        public ISpecificEntity GetEntity()
        {
            return new SpecificEntity { SpecificValue = "SpecificValue" };
        }
    }

    internal interface IAnotherSpecificContainer : IContainer<IAntoherSpecificEntity>
    {
    }

    internal class AnotherSpecificContainer : IAnotherSpecificContainer
    {
        public IAntoherSpecificEntity GetEntity()
        {
            return new AntoherSpecificEntity { AnotherSpecificValue = "AnotherSpecificValue" };
        }
    }

    internal interface IManager<TIdentifier> where TIdentifier : IIdentifier
    {
        IContainer<TIdentifier> Container { get; set; }
    }

    internal class SpecificEntityManager : IManager<ISpecificEntity>
    {
        public IContainer<ISpecificEntity> Container { get; set; }
    }

    internal class AnotherSpecificEntityManager : IManager<IAntoherSpecificEntity>
    {
        public IContainer<IAntoherSpecificEntity> Container { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I get an InvalidCastException in `Main()` in line 12.

I know that `ISpecificEntity` implements `IIdentifier`.
But obviously a direct cast from an `IManager<ISpecificEntity>` into an `IManager<IIdentifier>` does not work.

I thought working with covariance could do the trick but changing `IManager<TIdentifier>` into `IManager<in TIdentifier>` or `IManager<out TIdentifier>` does not work either.

So, is there a way do cast `specificManager` into an `IManager<IIdentifier>`?

Thanks and all the best.

Comment: It should tell you which line of Main() is problematic. Could you tell us that please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement generic polymorphism in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211072/how-to-implement-generic-polymorphism-in-c)

Comment: Don't repost, edit and improve your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you get the idea of generics wrong.

If you Look at Foo its a generic type.
Foo and Foo are NEW types, they do not derive from List, neither the types are conneted by means of inheritance. *Using generics creates new types, its does not derive!*

However what you are looking for is [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). This will allow you to create a kind of "generic polymorphism", but for that you need to specify this within your generic **definition**. Therefore it will only work for very few framework generics out of the box.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IManager<IIdentifier> f1 = new C1();
        IManager<IIdentifier> f2 = new SpecificEntityManager(); //IManager<ISpecificEntity>
    }
}

interface IIdentifier { }
interface ISpecificEntity : IIdentifier { }
interface IManager<out T> { }

class C1 : IManager<IIdentifier> { }
class SpecificEntityManager : IManager<ISpecificEntity> { }
```

Here is what YOU have to change:

```
internal interface IContainer<out TIdentifier> where TIdentifier : IIdentifier 
{ 
    TIdentifier GetEntity(); 
}
internal interface IManager<out TIdentifier> where TIdentifier : IIdentifier 
{
    IContainer<IIdentifier> Container { get; }
}
internal class SpecificEntityManager : IManager<ISpecificEntity>
{
    public IContainer<IIdentifier> Container { get; set; }
}
internal class AnotherSpecificEntityManager : IManager<IAntoherSpecificEntity>
{
    public IContainer<IIdentifier> Container { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: actually i got it, it works if you use the syntax correctly. added a code sample.

Comment: Perfect! This works in the sample code. I hope I can use it in production! ;-) Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a non-generic IManager that IManager<TIdentifier> can inherit from. Then IManager<IIdentifer> is an IManager and can be casted?

Comment: If there would be generic 'ISuperManager' that IManager would inherit from, how could I access to the generic property Container?

Comment: Not necessarily. IManager<TIdentifier> could inherit from an empty IManager that's not generic. The IManager<TIdentifier>'s are IManagers... I think.