# IList<InterfaceType> to List<ImplementsInterfaceType>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have a interface that is widely implemented, that has a IList with a certain interface.
Instead of lots of text, have a look here:

```
interface ILanguage
{
    IList<ITriggers> CompletionTriggers { get; set; }
}

public class Language : ILanguage
{
    public Constructor()
    {
        CompletionTriggers = new List<CompletionTrigger>();
    }
}
```

This is basically what I'm trying to do. The "Triggers" is a member of an interface, which is implemented by several types. But each type needs a custom ITrigger implementation and List for that matter (I use IList as it seems quite convenient).

The error says "Missing a cast?", but I find that weird as both are objects that **directly** implement both IList and ITrigger, (List and CompletionTrigger).

I figure that this is an easy thing, but some points as to why it behaves like this is well appreciated!

Comment: What version of .NET are you targetting?

Comment: Are you thinking about [covariance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/245607/11683)?

Comment: That was a nice link! Bookmarked. Thank you for that. I changed it to "CompletionTriggers = new List<ITrigger>();" then, I just add the custom triggers like so: "CompletionTriggers.Add(new CompletionTrigger());" Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I figure that this is an easy thing

It's not easy. At least not *that* easy. The reason this is not allowed is best explained with an example. Suppose it was allowed to do the assignments like you suggest:

```
// Let's make another trigger unrelated to CompletionTrigger
class ContinuationTrigger : ITrigger {
}
// This is allowed
List<CompletionTrigger> myTriggers = new List<CompletionTrigger>();
// THIS WILL NOT WORK (but let's pretend that it does)
IList<ITriggers> CompletionTriggers = myTriggers;
// Here comes trouble:
CompletionTriggers.Add(new ContinuationTrigger());
```

Since `CompletionTriggers` is of type `IList<ITriggers>` and `ContinuationTrigger` is an `ITrigger`, the compiler must allow the `Add` call. But that would put a continuation trigger into `myTriggers`, a collection that has been created as a `List<CompletionTrigger>`, which is definitely not allowed.

You have several choices as far as overcoming this goes. The simplest one is treating `ITrigger` objects equally, differentiating only at the time of object creation. This may be tricky, and in some instances it would require multiple dispatch.

Another option is making generic covers for getting and setting elements of `CompletionTriggers`:

```
void SetCompletionTriggers<T>(IList<T> triggers) where T : ITrigger {
    CompletionTriggers = triggers.Cast<ITrigger>().ToList();
}
IEnumerable<T> GetCompletionTriggers<T>() where T : ITrigger {
    return CompletionTriggers.Cast<T>();
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Now I quite understand what is going on. Now I initialize the "CompletionTriggers" as "new List<ITrigger>()" then I add the "custom" triggers in afterwards (that implement ITrigger directly". 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are going to define the list as `IList<ITriggers>` then when you new it it has to be `new List<ITriggers>`.

If you really want to create the list of a specific type, you could make your interface generic

```
interface ITriggers
{
}

class CompletionTrigger : ITriggers
{
}

interface ILanguage<T> where T: ITriggers
{
    List<T> CompletionTriggers { get; set; }
}

class Language : ILanguage<CompletionTrigger>
{
    public List<CompletionTrigger> CompletionTriggers { get; set; }
    public Language()
    {
        CompletionTriggers = new List<CompletionTrigger>();
    }
}
```