# Using where constraints with generic interface or class

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose we write a system for tests. Test contains the list of tasks and each task contains question and the list of answers. Also we assume that question or answer can be not only the text, but image for example. So we use generics:

```
public interface IQuestion<T>
{
    T Content { get; }
}

public interface IAnswer<T>
{
    T Content { get; }
    bool IsCorrect { get; }
}
```

And the problem occurs when we creating the Task:

```
interface ITask<TQuestion, TAnswer> 
{
    TQuestion Question { get; }
    List<TAnswer> Answers { get; }
}
```

**How to write that `TQuestion` should be subtype of `IQuestion` and `TAnswer` - subtype of `IAnswer`?**

I've tryed:

```
interface ITask<TQuestion, TAnswer> 
    where TQuestion : IQuestion<object>
    where TAnswer : IAnswer<object>
```

But when I created:

```
class TextQuestion : IQuestion<string> {...}
class TextAnswer : IAnswer<string> {...}
```

This did not work:

```
class TextTask : ITask<TextQuestion, TextAnswer>
```

Becouse, in fact, `IQuestion<string>` don't inherited from `IQuestion<object>`.

In *Java*, I would use wildcards in restriction of `ITask` generic types, in *Kotlin*, the above approach would have worked.

But how to solve it using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a third parameter:

```
interface ITask<TQuestion, TAnswer, T> 
    where TQuestion : IQuestion<T>
    where TAnswer : IAnswer<T>
```

As you know, `IQuestion<string>` don't inherited from `IQuestion<object>`, but this way you can have `TQuestion` be `IQuestion<string>`.

---

Addendum: having `TQuestion` be `IQuestion<object>` is only a problem because `IQuestion` doesn't have [variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654058.aspx) defined (so, it is invariant by default). If you define as I show below, you can use`IQuestion<object>` (the same goes for `IAnswer`).

```
public interface IQuestion<out T>
{
    T Content { get; }
}

public interface IAnswer<out T>
{
    T Content { get; }
    bool IsCorrect { get; }
}

interface ITask<TQuestion, TAnswer> 
    where TQuestion : IQuestion<object>
    where TAnswer : IAnswer<object>
{
    TQuestion Question { get; }
    List<TAnswer> Answers { get; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer; Jon Skeet explained why you have to explicitly say you want variance in generics in his book C# in depth (btw, it's a must read). In short, it's to avoid type mismatch at execution time. You can see this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/246101/574059 and this article by Eric Lippert : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

Comment: @gobes I'm aware of the reason behind. This falls back to what OP wants, for instance using variance in this case will be less restrictive than using a third parameter (more akin to what Java does), Codor's solution is somewhere in the middle. And thanks for the links.

Comment: That's it! Using variance, I got what I wanted initially: `class TextTask : ITask<TextQuestion, TextAnswer>`.

Answer (score 4):

In the way I understand the question, you can formulate the constraint by introduction of an additional type parameter in `ITask` as follows, omitting the type parameters `TQuestion` and `TAnswer` used before.

```
interface ITask<T> 
{
    IQuestion<T> Question { get; }
    List<IAnswer<T>> Answers { get; }
}
```