# Why can't I set a Dictionary<string, IReadOnlySet<string>> from a Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I can do this

```
IReadOnlySet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
```

but I can't do this:

```
Dictionary<string, IReadOnlySet<string>> dictSet = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
```

and I'm wondering why this is so?

Can this cast be done somehow or is it a case of having to create a whole new Dictionary? It seems rather inefficient to have to do this:

```
var dictSetPrep = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
// Here we would add items to dictSetPrep

var dictSet = new Dictionary<string, IReadOnlySet<string>>();
foreach (var kvp in dictSetPrep) {
    dictSet.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: In short - because C# does not support variance for classes.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246101/2501279)

Comment: There's no need to create a new dictionary. Your `Dictionary<string, IReadOnlySet<string>>` will still accept `HashSet<string>` values, it just can't be assigned a dictionary that, in its contract, will *only* accept `HashSet<string>` values and not any `IReadOnlySet<string>`, as the declaration is promising.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers here everyone and apologies for the duplicate question thing. As soon as variance and covariance were mentioned I remembered falling over something similar in the past. I guess I can't escape the expectation that this should just work - it instinctively feels like something you should be able to do, to me at least!